# Attack, Decay, Sustain, Release

Tags: code-golf, number, graphical-output, music

[Sound synthesizers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthesizer) use envelope generators to control how certain parameters of the sound (such as overall loudness) change with time. In many synthesizers an envelope is defined by four parameters, as represented in the following figure from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthesizer#Attack_Decay_Sustain_Release_.28ADSR.29_envelope):

- **Attack time (A)**: time taken for the envelope to reach its maximum level, starting from zero, when the key is first pressed.
- **Decay time (D)**: time taken for the envelope to reach the specified sustain level.
- **Sustain level (S)**: level which is maintained, after the initial attack and decay, for as long as the key is being pressed.
- **Release time (R)**: time taken for the envelope to reach zero when the key is released.

[image]

## The challenge

Input the four parameters A, D, S, R and **plot the envelope**.

Parameters will be **integer values from 0 to 127**.

The **maximum level** (reached at the end of the attack phase) will be assumed to be **127**.

The **horizontal segment at the sustain level** will be assumed to have **duration 64** (in the actual sound this duration is not fixed, but is determined by the amount of time that the key is held).

## Format and further details

The output should be an image in raster or vector format. If it's raster, the polygonal line should occupy at least 50 pixels vertically an horizontally.

The image can be either displayed or produced as a file in a standard image format. The file can be written to disk, or its exact contents can be output, either to STDERR or as function return argument.

The graph need only contain the polygonal line that defines the envelope. The scale of each axis can be freely chosen. Other elements such as axis lines, numeric labels or line colors are optional.

Input means and format are [flexible](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) as usual. For example, you can take the four numbers in any order, or an array containing them. [A program or a function](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet) can be provided. [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.

Shortest code in bytes wins.

## Test cases

Input is in the format `[A D S R]`. Note that the scale is different in each figure (in accordance with the rule that scale can be freely chosen)

```
[15 30 70 40]
```

[image]

```
[64 64 64 64]
```

[image]

```
[0 10 50 80]
```

[image]

```
[0 0 90 80]
```

[image]

```
[5 50 0 0]
```

[image]

```
[5 50 0 80]
```

[image]

```
[24 32 127 48]
```

[image]

Comment: I was expecting a [more simian challenge from the title](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attack_Decay_Sustain_Release)!

Comment: @Ben That reference was intended too :-) I love [_Sleep deprivation_](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iC4lOdiV2jk)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## MATL, <s>31</s> 22 bytes

```
Oii64ivYsO127itO5$h&XG
```

Accepts four separate inputs ordered as `A`, `D`, `R`, `S`

Try it out at [**MATL Online**](https://matl.io/?code=Oii64ivYsO127itO5%24h%26XG&inputs=15%0A30%0A40%0A70&version=19.7.4)

**Explanation**

```
0   % Push a literal 0 to the stack
ii  % Grab the first two inputs
64  % Push the number literal 64 to the stack
i   % Grab the third input
v   % Vertically concatenate all values
Ys  % Compute the cumulative sum
0   % Push the number literal 0 to the stack
127 % Push the number literal 127 to the stack
i   % Grab the fourth input
t   % Duplicate the fourth input
O   % Push the number literal 0 to the stack
5$h % Concatenate the last 5 elements on the stack
&XG % Plot the result using the first array as x and second array as y
```

[image]

Answer (score 44):

## TikZ, <s>195</s> <s>193</s> <s>181</s> <s>177</s> <s>172</s> <s>167</s> <s>163</s> <s>160</s> 159 bytes

*Thanks to David Carlisle for his helpful answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/372621/124071)*

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}\begin{document}\tikz\def~#1{\typein[#1];}~\a~\s~\d~\r\def\u{)--(\a+\d}\draw(,)--(\a,127\u,\s\u+64,\s\u+\r+64,);\end{document}
```

Yes, you heard right ***TikZ***.

### Explanation

This uses a couple of techniques to achieve its goal.  The first thing is input.  Most people might not know that L<sup>A</sup>T<sub>E</sub>X can take input.  Well it can.  This is achieved with the command `\typein`.  This will halt the compiler and request input from the user as assign it to a variable.

The other main technique is the use of `\def`.  `\def` in Tikz is absurdly powerful.  It essentially defines a piece of code and pastes it everywhere you call the variable.  In this code we define two things `\typein[#1]{}` so that we can assign our variables golfily and `)--(\a+\d` because this code shows up a bunch of times in the ungolfed version.

Here are two versions of the code (without the wrapper):

#### Golfed:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}\begin{document}\tikz\def~#1{\typein[#1];}~\a~\s~\d~\r\def\u{)--(\a+\d}\draw(,)--(\a,127\u,\s\u+64,\s\u+\r+64,);\end{document}
```

#### Ungolfed:

```
\typein[\a]{}\typein[\s]{}\typein[\d]{}\typein[\r]{}\draw(0,0)--(\a,127)--(\a+\d,)--(\a+\d+64,)--(\a+\d+\r+64,0);
```

### Image:

Since I cannot upload a pdf image directly, and converting it to any other format seems to cause the line to disappear altogether, here is what an image might look like when opened in Preview (input for this image is `[64 64 64 64]`):

[image: Preview image]

As you can see it is very thin.  However because it is a PDF image and not a raster image does not have to comply with thickness requirements.

Comment: I sincerely admire the fact that you know TikZ so well that it's the first solution that comes into your mind. (And if it wasn't, that's what legend will remember)

Comment: Doesn't `input tikz\begin{document}` work?

Comment: how about pictures? 

Comment: How do you actually render this? `pdflatex adsr.tex` doesn't seem to work. — Oh wait, it does work, I just didn't expect it would request interactive input!

Comment: @WheatWizard imagemagick can convert PDF reasonably well if you do it right

Comment: @WheatWizard maybe upload that PDF somewhere and I may try to deal with it…

Comment: @WheatWizard see proposed edit. The image looks strange tbh, not like the lines are thin, they are instead "squared" and very little contrast (which I fixed by -normalize option)
Did you use some lossy compression in PDF? like jpeg, etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53705/discussion-between-wheat-wizard-and-sarge-borsch).

Answer (score 20):

## Python 2, <s>83</s> <s>80</s> 79 bytes

```python
from turtle import*
def f(A,D,S,R):X=A+D+64;map(goto,[A,A+D,X,X+R],[127,S,S,0])
```

[**Try it online**](https://trinket.io/python/874e164de0) (83-byte version, because it runs online)

Note that certain outputs may not be completely visible using Trinket, because of the way the canvas works. You'll need to download and install Python if you want it to work better.

#### Ungolfed:

```python
from turtle import*
A,D,S,R=input()
goto(A,127)
goto(A+D,S)
goto(A+D+64,S)
goto(A+D+64+R,0)
```

This version doesn't work in Trinket, because Trinket doesn't support value unpacking of input.

Comment: You can use `map` in Python 2: `lambda A,D,S,R:map(goto,[A,A+D,A+D+64,A+D+R+64],[127,S,S,0])`

Comment: @xnor I get `SuspensionError: Cannot call a function that blocks or suspends here on line undefined in main.py` on Trinket. Have you confirmed that it works? I'm not sure if the error is unique to Trinket or not.

Comment: Works for me in 2.7.12.

Comment: @xnor Mmk, thanks. It's probably a limitation in Skulpt.

Comment: I submitted a simpler version of this program as an example to the Skulpt github repo, and they thought it was a nice find. Hopefully they'll be able to fix it, but the pace of their "turtle sprint" seems to be more of a walk.

Answer (score 17):

### Mathematica, <s>61</s> 58 bytes

```
ListLinePlot[{Accumulate@{0,##3,64,#2},{0,127,#,#,0}}]&
```

`` is the operator for `Transpose` and is rendered as a superscript `T` by Mathematica.

Takes the arguments in the order `S, R, A, D` and returns a vector graphics object.

Results for all seven test cases:

[image]
<sup>Click for larger version.</sup>

Comment: That was quick!

Comment: +1 for teaching me `ListLinePlot` :) And there's a `ListStepPlot` as well—so useful!

Answer (score 12):

### R, <s>66</s> 63 bytes

```
function(A,D,S,R)plot(cumsum(c(0,A,D,64,R)),c(0,127,S,S,0),"l")
```

Displays the image, with axis labs being `cumsum(c(0,A,D,64,R))` and `c(0,127,S,S,0)`, as well axis lines and numeric labels.

Thanks to @Zahiro Mor for shaving off *3 bytes* !

**Previous answer :**

```
function(A,D,S,R)plot(c(0,A,A+D,b<-A+D+64,b+R),c(0,127,S,S,0),"l")
```

Comment: you can use `cumsum(c(0,A,D,64,R))`  to replace the first term in the plot. with cumsum you will not need the b trick and still shave 3 bytes :)  `function(A,D,S,R)plot(cumsum(c(0,A,D,64,R)),c(0,127,S,S,0),"l")`

Answer (score 11):

## Matlab, 50 bytes

```
@(A,D,S,R)plot(cumsum([0,A,D,64,R]),[0,127,S,S,0])
```

This yields an anonymous function "ans" that has to be called as ans(A,D,S,R).

Answer (score 9):

### JavaScript (ES6) + HTML, 126 + 23 = 149

```js
c=O.getContext`2d`;c.moveTo(a=0,z=O.height=128);g=(y,x=prompt())=>c.lineTo(a+=+x,y)||g;g(0)(s=z+~prompt())(s,64)(z);c.stroke()
```

```html
<canvas id=O width=512>
```

Takes input one at a time in the order `A, S, D, R`.

Answer (score 9):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>114</s> 111 bytes

```js
f=(a,d,s,r)=>`<svg width=446 height=128><path stroke=red fill=none d=M0,127L${a},0l${d},${127-s}h64l${r},${s}>`
```

```html
<div oninput=o.innerHTML=f(a.value,d.value,s.value,r.value)><input type=number value=0 min=0 max=127 id=a><input type=number value=63 min=0 max=127 id=d><input type=number value=127 min=0 max=127 id=s><input type=number value=0 min=0 max=127 id=r><div id=o><svg width=446 height=128><path stroke=red fill=none d=M0,127L0,0l63,0h64l0,127 /></svg>
```

Returns an SVG image suitable for `innerHTML`. Add 18 bytes for valid XML.

Comment: It's great how the figure is updated in real time!

Comment: This is great, I should learn SVG syntax sometime. Perhaps add default values to the `<input>`s?

Comment: @ETHproductions Did you have any particular defaults in mind? (Given that setting defaults won't actually trigger the initial graph anyway...)

Comment: I was thinking perhaps just `64,64,64,64`. Normally I'd hardcode the correct output for the default input, but I see how that would be difficult here...

Answer (score 8):

### Haskell, <s>112</s> 110 bytes

```
import Graphics.Gloss
(a#d)s r=display(InWindow""(600,300)(0,0))red$line$zip(scanl(+)0[a,d,64,r])[0,127,s,s,0]
```

Usage example: `(0#10) 50 80`.

[image: adsr envelope]

This uses the `Gloss` library. The `display` function expects a window to plot in (here: a window without title (`""`), size 600x300, position `(0,0)` on desktop), a background color (`red`) and picture witch is a line along the path made by zipping the cumulative sum of `[0,a,d,64,r]` = `[0,a,a+d,a+d+64,a+d+64+r]` as the x coordinates and `[0,127,s,s,0]` as the y coordinates.

Edit: Thanks @xnor for 2 bytes!

Comment: Should be shorter to write `scanl(+)0[a,d,64,r]`

Answer (score 5):

## Processing, <s>134</s> 108 + 14(call to `size`) = <s>148</s> 122 bytes

First we need a call to `size` somewhere in the program so that the output will fit in the window (default at 100x100).

```
size(400,400);
```

And here's the actual function:

```
void g(int a,int b,int c,int d){line(0,127,a,0);line(a,0,b+=a,c=127-c);line(b,c,b+=64,c);line(b,c,b+d,127);}
```

Call it like `f(15,20,70,40);`

#### Screenshot

```
15, 20, 70, 40
```

[image]

---

My newer answer is more straightforward than the older answer, but I like the older one more (even if it is bigger).

#### Old answer (148 bytes)

```
size(400,400);
```

and the two functions

```
void f(int[]v){translate(0,127);l(v[0],-127);l(v[1],127-v[2]);l(64,0);l(v[3],v[2]);}void l(int x,int y){line(0,0,x,y);translate(x,y);}
```

Call it like `f(int_array_containing_values);` and the result will look something like: `f(new int[]{15,20,70,40});`

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, <s>149</s> 130 bytes

```php
[,$a,$d,$s,$r]=$argv;imagepolygon($i=imagecreatetruecolor(446,127),[0,127,$a,0,$d+=$a,$s,$d+=64,$s,$d+$r,127],5,999);imagepng($i);
```

takes input from command line arguments, writes image (PNG with graph blue on black) to stdout. Requires PHP 7.1 or later.

usage e.g.

```
# any OS with ImageMagick:
php -r '<code>' <parameters> | display

# linux with feh:
php -r '<code>' <parameters> | feh
```

+4 bytes for older PHP: Replace `[,$a,$d,$s,$r]` with `list(,$a,$d,$s,$r)`.

---

There is a small hack in there: instead of using `imageopenpolygon` to hide the base line, the finishing polygon line is drawn outside the canvas. (y=127 would only display on an image with height >= 128.)

I could have saved more with color 99 or 9 instead of 999; but those are pretty hard to see on black. :)

Answer (score 4):

## SmileBASIC, 90 bytes

```
INPUT A,D,S,R
B=A+D+64W=#Y-S
GLINE.,#Y,A,0GLINE A,0,A+D,W
GLINE A+D,W,B,W
GLINE B,W,B+R,#Y
```

Answer (score 3):

### Bash + [grace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grace_(plotting_tool)), 70 bytes

```sh
t=$[$1+$2]
echo "0 0
$1 127
$t $3
$[t+64] $3
$[t+64+$4] 0">f
xmgrace f
```

The script writes to file `f` the coordinates of each point, and xmgrace (the GUI version) reads the file and displays the plot using lines by default.

**Run**:

```sh
./plot_ADSR.sh 15 30 70 40
```

**Output:** (print screen)

[image: 15 30 70 40]

I think this can be done directly by a grace script, if it can accept input, but I'm not familiar with its syntax. I'll look into it.

**Explanation:**

```
t=$[$1+$2]          # store the value of (A+D) for later usage
echo "0 0           # start writing the coordinates to file "f", first the origin
$1 127              # then (A, 127)
$t $3               # then (A + D, S)
$[t+64] $3          # then (A + D + 64, S)
$[t+64+$4] 0">f     # then (A + D + 64 + R, 0)
xmgrace f           # call xmgrace to plot the generated XY file
```

Answer (score 2):

### Go, <s>947</s> <s>915</s> 506 bytes

*This is far from optimized, trying to learn the language while participating in these questions. Feel free to point out what I can do.*

[image: fixed image]

**Condensed:**

```
package main;import (."os";."image";k"image/png";c"image/color";."strconv";."math");func main(){g:=NewRGBA(Rect(0,0,127*4,127));a,_:=ParseFloat(Args[1],4);d,_:=ParseFloat(Args[2],4);s,_:=ParseFloat(Args[3],4);r,_:=ParseFloat(Args[4],4);z:=[5][]float64{{0,0},{a,127},{a+d,s},{a+d+64,s},{a+d+64+r,0}};for i:=1;i<len(z);i++{v,w,x,y:=z[i-1][0],z[i-1][1],z[i][0],z[i][1];m:=(y-w)/(x-v);t:=y-m*x;for v<=x{g.Set(int(Ceil(v)),127-int(Ceil(w)),c.RGBA{0,0,0,255});v+=.01;w=m*v+t}};f,_:=Create("o.png");k.Encode(f,g)}
```

**Uncondenced:**

```
package main

import (
    ."os"
    ."image"
    k"image/png"
    c"image/color"
    ."strconv"
    ."math"
    "fmt"
)

func main(){
    g := NewRGBA(Rect(0, 0, 127*4, 127))

    a, _ := ParseFloat(Args[1], 4)
    d, _ := ParseFloat(Args[2], 4)
    s, _ := ParseFloat(Args[3], 4)
    r, _ := ParseFloat(Args[4], 4)

    z := [5][]float64{{0,0},{a,127},{a+d,s},{a+d+64,s},{a+d+64+r,0}}
    for i:=1;i<len(z);i++{
        v,w,x,y:=z[i-1][0],z[i-1][1],z[i][0],z[i][1]
        m:=(y-w)/(x-v)
        t:=y-m*x
        for v<=x{
            g.Set(int(Ceil(v)),127-int(Ceil(w)), c.RGBA{0,0,0,255})
            v+=.01
            w=m*v+t
        }
    }
    f,_:=Create("o.png")
    k.Encode(f,g)
}
```

Comment: @LuisMendo it is. By default 0,0 is top left. Ill inverse everything as soon as I can.

Comment: Did you also update the golfed version and its byte count?

Comment: I never coded in go, so I don't know. Users here golf their code manually because they can save more bytes than a general minifier. Bad coding practices and tricks are welcomed here. For ex, wouldn't replacing struct objects with variables (like l1x, l1y, l1X, l1Y) be golfier perhaps?

Comment: @rugdealer [This](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/41862/36398) may help, in case you haven't seen it

Comment: Lost almost 400 bytes thanks to your link @LuisMendo

Comment: @seshoumara you're right. I was able to lose a lot from removing the structs.

Comment: @rugdealer Wow, that's a lot \o/

Comment: Very good, keep at it. For example, why do you work with floats and need `Ceil` if the input is integer numbers and a few coordinates are just a sum of ints? Also, `Rect(0,0,127*4,127)` can be `Rect(0,0,508,127)`, and a file on Linux doesn't need an extension `Create("o")`.

Comment: @seshoumara, seeing that Go does not provide a draw line function, I need to do it myself. If for example I have coords (0,0) and (1,3) I will be unable to draw the line that links them both with just ints. I use floats instead to be able to calculate the points in between, then I do a rough estimate as to where those points would be as an int. Unsure if what I'm saying is clear. In any case, this allows me to draw complete lines and not just dots. And yes I forgot that little detail for linux. Thanks!

Comment: Ouch, that's why. Maybe ask in the chat or check on the [PPCG meta](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/) about using external libraries. I never needed them. I googled [this](https://github.com/llgcode/draw2d) as one such example for go.

Answer (score 1):

### dc, 120 bytes

Initially I thought I can't answer in dc, but I see that printing the syntax of a vector image is allowed.

```
?sR127r-sS[<svg><path d="M0 127 L]nrdn[ 0 L]n+dn32PlSn[ L]n64+dn32PlSn[ L]nlR+n[ 127" fill="none" stroke="red"/></svg>]p
```

The code calculates the translated coordinates of each point and generates the SVG syntax for the plot. Since an image editor has the origin at the top-left corner, I had to subtract the `y` values from `height`, 127 in this case, so that the image is shown as if the origin is at the bottom-left corner.

**Run example:** or [**Try it Online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/dc#@29fHGRoZF6kWxwcbVNclm5nU5BYkqGQYqvka6AAlFDwic0rSsmLVjAAsbRT8oyNAnKCgXwgz8wElZ8TpA1kADUpKaRl5uTYKuXl56UqKRSXFOVnp9oqFaWmKOnb2eiDbIkt@P/f0FTB2EDB3EDBxAAA)

```sh
dc -f plot_ADSR.dc <<< "15 30 70 40"
```

**Output:**

```html
<svg><path d="M0 127 L15 0 L45 57 L109 57 L149 127" fill="none" stroke="red"/></svg>
```

To display the image plot, save that exact output to a file and open it with Gimp, for example, or enter the text in an html page as I did above.

**Explanation:** `dc` is a reverse-polish **d**esk **c**alculator stack language

The script is a long concatenation of the SVG syntax string. The keyword `M` stands for *move to coordinate* and `L` stands for *draw line from current position to given coordinate*.

```
?                           # read input (in reverse order by default). Stack: RSDA
sR                          # pop top value, store it in register 'R'. Stack: SDA
127r-sS                     # push 127, swap top 2 values, pop them and push
                            #subtracting result, save it to 'S', pop it. Stack: DA
[<svg><path d="M0 127 L]n   # [..]n print string (push then pop). Stack: unchanged
rdn                         # swap, duplicate top, print (A) and pop it. Stack: AD
[ 0 L]n                     # printing
+dn                         # pop top 2 values, push addition result, duplicate it,
                            #print and pop it. Stack: (A+D)
32P                         # print a space
lSn                         # push value from register 'S', print and pop it.
                            #Stack: unchanged
[ L]n                       # printing
64+dn                       # push 64, pop top 2 values, push addition result,
                            #duplicate it, print and pop it. Stack: (A+D+64)
32PlSn[ L]n                 # print space, print register 'S', more printing
lR+n                        #push value from register 'R', pop top 2 values, push
                            #addition result, print it and pop it. Stack: empty
[ 127" fill="none" stroke="red"/></svg>]p   # printing
```

Answer (score 1):

## Processing, 111 bytes

```
size(400,128);line(0,127,a,0),line(a,0,a+d,127-s),line(a+d,127-s,a+d+64,127-s),line(a+d+64,127-s,a+d+64+r,127);
```

Used a simpler method of input compared to user41805.

### Output (formatted)

`0,0,90,80`

[image]

`0,10,50,80`

[image]

`5,50,0,0`

[image]

`5,50,0,80`

[image]

`15,30,70,40`

[image]

`24,32,127,48`

[image]

`64,64,64,64`

[image]

### Ungolfed code with formatting

```
void settings() {
  //size adjusts according to params
  size(a+d+64+r, 129);
}
void setup() {
  translate(1,0);
  background(255); 
  strokeWeight(3);
  
  //axes
  line(0,127,600,127);
  line(0,0,0,127);
  
  //graph
  stroke(53,113,9);
  line(0,127,a,0);
  stroke(228,77,40);
  line(a,0,a+d,127-s);
  stroke(26,39,232);
  line(a+d,127-s,a+d+64,127-s);
  stroke(110,27,109);
  line(a+d+64,127-s,a+d+64+r,127);
  
  //save to file
  save("a"+a+"d"+d+"s"+s+"r"+r+".png");
}
int a=24,d=32,s=127,r=48;
```

This program will save your images to disk in the same folder.