# These are the Frequencies, Kenneth

Tags: code-golf, math

## The Challenge

Generate 1 sec of an 8 bit tone sampled at 256 samples per second. The tone will be made up of a number of sine waves. The frequency of each sine wave will be determined from the input data.

These are deep tones, too low for a human to perceive, but I've chosen 8 bit numbers here since it's code-golf.

## The Input

You will receive an array (or a list) of (non-negative) 8 bit signed integer values (0-127), each number will represent a frequency. An empty list is allowed and numbers may appear more than once in the list. All input frequencies must be assumed to be equal in amplitude.

## The Output

Your program or function must output an array (or list) of 8 bit signed integer values that represents the signal generated.

Some graphical examples follow, but the actual output of your program is to be a list of integers. ***Not*** a graph and ***not*** a stream of bytes.

Also, your output must be *normalized*. That is, it must fill the window of possible values from -128 to 127. In other words, if you calculate a signal and its [min,max] is [-64,63], then you must amplify (multiply) the entire signal ×2. A flat signal will be all zeros. There should be no DC component in any output signal (ie. the average value should be 0). Since most (practically all) generated signals will be symmetrical then most likely your normalized signal will never contain a -128.

[image]

The actual expected output of these datasets are as follows:

```
[]                                    => [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
[2]                                   => [0,6,12,18,24,30,36,42,48,54,59,65,70,75,80,85,89,94,98,102,105,108,112,114,117,119,121,123,124,125,126,126,127,126,126,125,124,123,121,119,117,114,112,108,105,102,98,94,89,85,80,75,70,65,59,54,48,42,36,30,24,18,12,6,0,-6,-12,-18,-24,-30,-36,-42,-48,-54,-59,-65,-70,-75,-80,-85,-89,-94,-98,-102,-105,-108,-112,-114,-117,-119,-121,-123,-124,-125,-126,-126,-127,-126,-126,-125,-124,-123,-121,-119,-117,-114,-112,-108,-105,-102,-98,-94,-89,-85,-80,-75,-70,-65,-59,-54,-48,-42,-36,-30,-24,-18,-12,-6,0,6,12,18,24,30,36,42,48,54,59,65,70,75,80,85,89,94,98,102,105,108,112,114,117,119,121,123,124,125,126,126,127,126,126,125,124,123,121,119,117,114,112,108,105,102,98,94,89,85,80,75,70,65,59,54,48,42,36,30,24,18,12,6,0,-6,-12,-18,-24,-30,-36,-42,-48,-54,-59,-65,-70,-75,-80,-85,-89,-94,-98,-102,-105,-108,-112,-114,-117,-119,-121,-123,-124,-125,-126,-126,-127,-126,-126,-125,-124,-123,-121,-119,-117,-114,-112,-108,-105,-102,-98,-94,-89,-85,-80,-75,-70,-65,-59,-54,-48,-42,-36,-30,-24,-18,-12,-6]
[1,3]                                 => [0,8,16,24,32,39,47,54,61,68,75,81,87,93,98,103,107,111,115,118,120,123,124,126,126,126,126,126,125,123,121,119,116,113,110,106,102,98,94,89,84,79,74,69,64,59,54,49,44,39,35,30,26,22,18,15,12,9,7,4,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,4,7,9,12,15,18,22,26,30,35,39,44,49,54,59,64,69,74,79,84,89,94,98,102,106,110,113,116,119,121,123,125,126,126,127,126,126,124,123,120,118,115,111,107,103,98,93,87,81,75,68,61,54,47,39,32,24,16,8,0,-8,-16,-24,-32,-39,-47,-54,-61,-68,-75,-81,-87,-93,-98,-103,-107,-111,-115,-118,-120,-123,-124,-126,-126,-127,-126,-126,-125,-123,-121,-119,-116,-113,-110,-106,-102,-98,-94,-89,-84,-79,-74,-69,-64,-59,-54,-49,-44,-39,-35,-30,-26,-22,-18,-15,-12,-9,-7,-4,-3,-1,0,0,0,0,0,-1,-3,-4,-7,-9,-12,-15,-18,-22,-26,-30,-35,-39,-44,-49,-54,-59,-64,-69,-74,-79,-84,-89,-94,-98,-102,-106,-110,-113,-116,-119,-121,-123,-125,-126,-126,-126,-126,-126,-124,-123,-120,-118,-115,-111,-107,-103,-98,-93,-87,-81,-75,-68,-61,-54,-47,-39,-32,-24,-16,-8]
[15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1] => [0,32,63,89,109,122,126,124,114,100,82,62,43,26,13,4,0,0,3,9,16,24,30,35,37,36,33,27,21,14,8,3,0,-1,0,2,6,10,15,18,21,21,21,18,15,10,6,2,0,-1,-1,0,1,5,8,11,13,15,15,14,11,8,5,2,0,-1,-2,-1,0,1,4,6,9,10,11,11,9,7,5,2,0,-1,-2,-3,-2,0,1,3,6,7,8,9,8,6,4,2,0,-1,-3,-3,-3,-2,0,1,3,5,6,7,7,6,4,2,0,-2,-3,-4,-4,-4,-2,0,1,3,4,5,5,5,4,2,0,-2,-4,-5,-5,-5,-4,-3,-1,0,2,4,4,4,3,2,0,-2,-4,-6,-7,-7,-6,-5,-3,-1,0,2,3,3,3,1,0,-2,-4,-6,-8,-9,-8,-7,-6,-3,-1,0,2,3,2,1,0,-2,-5,-7,-9,-11,-11,-10,-9,-6,-4,-1,0,1,2,1,0,-2,-5,-8,-11,-14,-15,-15,-13,-11,-8,-5,-1,0,1,1,0,-2,-6,-10,-15,-18,-21,-21,-21,-18,-15,-10,-6,-2,0,1,0,-3,-8,-14,-21,-27,-33,-36,-37,-35,-30,-24,-16,-9,-3,0,0,-4,-13,-26,-43,-62,-82,-100,-114,-124,-127,-122,-109,-89,-63,-32]
[3,5,7,11,13,17,23]                   => [0,47,88,115,126,123,107,86,65,48,38,35,36,38,38,35,29,21,14,12,14,22,32,40,45,43,34,20,3,-10,-19,-22,-17,-10,-2,0,-3,-14,-30,-48,-60,-64,-56,-36,-7,22,49,66,70,60,40,14,-11,-31,-42,-44,-38,-29,-20,-14,-12,-14,-19,-23,-25,-23,-19,-14,-12,-14,-20,-29,-38,-44,-42,-31,-11,14,40,60,70,66,49,22,-7,-36,-56,-64,-60,-48,-30,-14,-3,0,-2,-10,-17,-22,-19,-10,3,20,34,43,45,40,32,22,14,12,14,21,29,35,38,38,36,35,38,48,65,86,107,123,126,115,88,47,0,-47,-88,-115,-126,-123,-107,-86,-65,-48,-38,-35,-36,-38,-38,-35,-29,-21,-14,-12,-14,-22,-32,-40,-45,-43,-34,-20,-3,10,19,22,17,10,2,0,3,14,30,48,60,64,56,36,7,-22,-49,-66,-70,-60,-40,-14,11,31,42,44,38,29,20,14,12,14,19,23,25,23,19,14,12,14,20,29,38,44,42,31,11,-14,-40,-60,-70,-66,-49,-22,7,36,56,64,60,48,30,14,3,0,2,10,17,22,19,10,-3,-20,-34,-43,-45,-40,-32,-22,-14,-12,-14,-21,-29,-35,-38,-38,-36,-35,-38,-48,-65,-86,-107,-123,-127,-115,-88,-47]
[1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34]                => [0,52,88,99,90,75,68,73,84,92,88,74,60,56,67,87,104,104,85,55,30,25,43,73,101,112,105,85,66,57,58,59,51,34,14,4,15,46,87,118,127,112,84,60,50,56,68,73,64,45,27,18,23,32,36,24,1,-21,-28,-11,26,70,103,114,103,83,66,61,63,63,53,34,13,4,13,36,59,68,54,23,-8,-27,-24,-6,14,23,15,-2,-20,-28,-25,-19,-21,-34,-52,-62,-51,-17,31,77,103,104,88,68,57,60,69,74,67,49,32,24,31,45,54,47,23,-7,-29,-29,-6,26,55,64,54,32,12,1,0,-1,-12,-32,-54,-64,-55,-26,6,29,29,7,-23,-47,-54,-45,-31,-24,-32,-49,-67,-74,-69,-60,-57,-68,-88,-104,-103,-77,-31,17,51,62,52,34,21,19,25,28,20,2,-15,-23,-14,6,24,27,8,-23,-54,-68,-59,-36,-13,-4,-13,-34,-53,-63,-63,-61,-66,-83,-103,-114,-103,-70,-26,11,28,21,-1,-24,-36,-32,-23,-18,-27,-45,-64,-73,-68,-56,-50,-60,-84,-112,-126,-118,-87,-46,-15,-4,-14,-34,-51,-59,-58,-57,-66,-85,-105,-112,-101,-73,-43,-25,-30,-55,-85,-104,-104,-87,-67,-56,-60,-74,-88,-92,-84,-73,-68,-75,-90,-99,-88,-52]
```

## Additional Rules

All component frequencies are to begin at 0° phase. Basically, that means that they should start at 0 proceed to +127 at 90°, 0 again at 180°, -127 at 270° and then back to 0 at 360°.

It is acceptable if your outputs are slightly different due to rounding, from the examples posted here. They should be normalized to fill (or nearly fill) the range of possible signed ints (-128..127).

The [usual loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are prohibited.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest code wins.

## IMPORTANT!

Practically everybody has made the same mistake in this challenge. 128 is NOT a valid signed 8 bit integer. You should not have output that contains this number or any number over 128.

Comment: I recall one of my Physics teachers saying, on many occasion, that `sec` is not an abbreviation of `second` and to use the correct abbreviation, `s`.

Comment: ...Don't have your speakers too loud people, you may get sick.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/110037/attack-decay-sustain-release)

Comment: *an array of 8 bit signed integers* vs. *not a stream of bytes*.  In some languages (e.g. [tag:c]) an array of 8 bit signed integers is exactly the same as a stream of bytes.  Can that be resolved?

Comment: The statements "...must fill the window of possible values from -128 to 127" and "...at 0 proceed to +127 at 90°, 0 again at 180°, -127 at 270° and then back to 0 at 360°." are in conflict. I imagine it would be kindest to the developers to allow -128 to be left out if they wish.

Comment: @Jonathan, well, almost all of these generated signals will be (nearly) symmetrical so I don't see -128 appearing very often if at all. *normalization* should not normally add a dc component, but I'll clarify

Comment: @Digital Trauma, output the data as shown in the examples. A set of non-printable ASCII characters (a byte stream) would not be acceptable. This is still totally solvable in C/C++

Comment: For `[2]`, why does the 5th value (0-indexed) `30` instead of `31`? `128*sin(2*5/256*2*pi)` is `31.1014630276`

Comment: @Leaky Nun, don't care. close enough. Actually you should probably multiply by 127 or you'll get an overflow. Or you could clamp. I don't care which.

Comment: ...so shouldn't the output for `[3,5,7,11,13,17,23]` range from -128 to 127? (the example output has min -127 and max 126) - or is this within the "rounding" allowance?

Comment: @Jonathan Allan, "It is acceptable if your outputs are slightly different due to rounding"

Comment: _your output must be normalized. That is, it must fill the window of possible values from -128 to 127_ This contradicts the result for empty input. Can you clarify? Or maybe not consider empty input at all?

Comment: @Luis, what is the sentence immediately following that in the very same paragraph? Clarified! How else would you handle a zero signal. A little bit of common sense isn't out of the question.

Comment: @JonathanAllan my teachers told me never to use `secs` because physicists never have any.

Comment: @Octopus if this were done in C, what would the inputs and outputs be? char arrays or are int arrays acceptable? Or does the output actually need to be printed with commas and brackets?

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>23</s> 28 bytes

```
Ṁ1Ṁ?
⁹Ḷµ×³×ØP÷⁹ḤÆSSµ€µ×127:Ç
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzgZDILbnetS48@GObYe2Hp5@aPPh6YdnBBzeDhZacrgtOPjQ1kdNa0ByhkbmVofb////H22oY6hjpGOsY6pjoWNorGNkqGNsEgsA)

*+5 bytes for handling input []*

All rounding errors are within +/- 2.

**How it works**

```
Ṁ1Ṁ?  - helper link, returns the maximum of a list unless the maximum is 0, where it returns 1                  
  Ṁ?  - if the maximum is truthy:
Ṁ     - return the maximum. Else:
 1    - return 1.

⁹Ḷµ×³×ØP÷⁹ḤÆSSµ€µ×127:Ṁ - main link, nilad
⁹Ḷ                      - the literal [0,1,2,3,...,254,255]
  µ           µ€        - compute the relative amplitude for each using the chain:
   ×³                   - multiply each element frequency by x
     ×ØP÷⁹Ḥ             - scale because the sine function uses degrees.
           ÆS           - take the sine
             S          - return the sum of the list of sines of component waves.
                µ×127:Ç - scale to 127, with divison by 0 handled by the helper link
```

Comment: This does not give the desired result for empty input

Comment: [26 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R486HO7Yd2np4@qHNh6cfnhFweDtYaMnhtuDgQ1sfNa0ByRkamVs93NlgCMT2////jzaKBQA) `Ṁ1Ṁ?` doesn't need it's own line

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 119 bytes

```python
from math import*
def f(a):b=[sum(sin(m*i*pi/128)for m in a)for i in range(256)];return[127*x//(max(*b)or 1)for x in b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VhbbhtJEvwenYKfpNAN17uqZ8cn0eqDtqUdAZYsSDQgz@W9EZHZJEV49wIzIJvsR1ZWZmTkg3z@cfjz21P@@fP@5dvj5nF/@HPz8Pj87eVwffXl7n5zv93vfv/08eb1@@P29eFp@3j9cP388CGmsbv/9rJ53Dw8bfY6feDpy/7pP3fbVNvu9l8vd4fvL083MfXrtw8fto/7t@31px0ko@TfKP/p9ufh7vXwef969/rx5t9X25vb6SZM/7z@xq/b3XQFIiQxoU0xTXFMqUw5TLlNJU1lTLVMdZlanXqYep1GmAY@l2kp0zKmGLAmVBw45/pYcHQcC9RFHBkH7iXIpOZHPzuv/jybPNdpfTF91Cv9idthU2w9ZEaXSTAM5sFImAqDYTaMp8JBdxq8nNs043TGnRkPZjyfITZDesaiGWtnqJihaYbCGXpnqJ8Hv3Efe87YeqYJM22ZadQcpRNmzrR3puEzPZjpykyfZjo308v1o7@/rEe5vK6VFtNX1j20m@2bzBSaRNOGm9rddLpAV@gSXaOLdJUua6NhUBCWf8L99wm353mcsjIdWDXFHQAuU@nEs8WpDUU8TqNPS7ZwI0yB4WGoEBbBHM7C3H5x1Ivw4l7EdcS60C5CW6a@TB3bg3NlDS1sKrQsV0UXtoqpNABrpz7h6RTPChkcwz1YLU5X0TpxIZld5aTUOrm1XdfWo1ySu5mlsrhdEPt/kXoldDCEhFQ05IKABJwAFdACYMAMsOlnl5NJ/G2IClmIiDUnLqOJ6EJMEcaiGWuNsDiHwhl6naykVBCRxCvSx8If3lP0/7Pzgph8EHkvUktov@IkvoHj3Gkh06qccZLWF/MCYTBe0jtPT1lJfVgOSQjg@iysuOCtoseLp3X11E6mS@ldHSnf85jiblN3G0f5ZYq31UFztf0iuy8S@@LjlNNhhd0CENegBI8T48W4MX6MI@PJuAqt7kglz17oHmvmglEgSRa/ySxQHdmKgleVDLirzMbalsnoGMjbdOInlwekPgRQ5zOTIzJpiHNm4rS1EyBfugorhPpE7iNHIBMsOKyyTBDLsuhvT0@2leSRi0rMymoTZXqd3A1UGNxf5dIqirSkIUHyUYn@Tirz05K94dkQBuhbR5m8vlexKsF@EkoroeydjrWj6nWSIoPW94mYQE6vfC7XRM@uk3ommvWK7wSHeDxW8TPZdJSsR7pHP4Ium5QYVO@kh4sVzw4e2e4NCdiadUUzjcdEiqfjmJTWRg2eIDuHbSBJEjV7q@lnqe2kJYctf4tZwiwB5WYwbx5KubB2PMsdlSI9WCxDG9UnJz/j2FcSgZHWxJAuw2utOG6dajSOCGiGeYjJTSc6T4uTmTlU2CCQLQWKKvMh4w4zwbBZvEh1u04OQvR5gs22BS92zZDo1Ijq05rmlEDV1tTxPPr8wfXEnPqDhyz5N@8RrGrfKkFnzynPdVyvQpdMb5RPRVty40YjaHw3u2ifCqHbnX3f7HSQv939XXSdBUUhLARHZSWlM@giwSS8hm3zc6gH@KNZ51NHbIoQAoVwBatx41gfrXqunWs0m2hk5HBaNT/3awEXL4BJVjML9VdjWnbAssqJ8OCUGZS3mT4ABpobNHY0@uAYsIG05gNWMLVWtIA2Z@RCV0mmcEKEWwC1yk9ODEekgpAamj8SNayZWly9tmm2LbZX5YU9nFFkYdYuWVWCvohmUWVSlS6Ys3RazgdvIOkCpOjsqWeAttO1GF0tCNayrKF1jxWDVvpxjoyqWartmXTIRTlZE0O9YKAKPun0zBFr0f0un@hc5zQUQ9GBqbbaoKdE7IxZ9F8DlU8BT0UrGBoPuZcIz2ZSmhRpKu1aMmwP20bbA0kAw8eD0cn60cCO6KBY9UzKWs276pQwO3NjjsWZ76oSoZaJDwZp4QZo3MmqI6FKqvJR94ha8rQdltbR2cuA1WT1sEalH5jRu8/bhWBRdxc/bT7uTGubFcnD6gMkN@@eF@oRcARoktSa76N3imhUIDU0S9KCqsrcxOVF9M@naZNkYnlZJ1GlRT@b86C0dptglNGh@JzTu1bCKfgGF@FpVs1gkiASQ1lhjSZZUVVAElu67sjCYTMcSRrzsZUIumwNQke09Bl5HYLj0Q6bNhlcDSrz6k3zFMneALt5S0x69p1ZOD1Dx/GXmeoVl3CEK81cKF5Oi8VSs@9wbJr9ZrNfc/bjLtomxSs9qzEDYWLFP6ifYKt2BwOdIC/JB@58@imwcDpY7HlFy7y9uuJ/fl/2h/109/Z89/lw94X//x3//Pv96rf958P3/dfNx839lnK7q9@eXx6eDtv916/bm/2n1@3b/GP3x8e40b@H0w@u/@vheWvrjmp3t7vdz/8C)

Comment: `2*pi/256` -> `pi/128`

Comment: instead of `m*i*2*pi/256`, why not `m*i*pi/128`?

Comment: Save four bytes by writing the function on a single line.

Comment: Save five more more using `c=max(*b)or 1` and `127*x//c`

Comment: @JonathanAllan how to write the function on a single line? The `return` statement cannot start at the middle, and I cannot convert the function into a lambda.

Comment: (link too long for a comment with the test cases) like [this](https://tio.run/##Hcs9DsMgDEDhvafwaFgiqPqjVj1JlIGo0HiwQQ6R6Olpk@0b3ivfumQ59540M3CoCxCXrNWe3jFBwmAe82tcN8aVBNmSLTQ4fzcpKzCQQDhIOzXIJ6K/XM301Fg3lZGkYhuQQ0M7m3/ojHX@djxtf@ap9x8)

Comment: Or [with the other suggestion](https://tio.run/##Hco7DsMgDADQvafwaFgQVP2oVU8SZQAVGg8G5BCJnp422d7w6rctJZ/HSFIY2LcFiGuRpk/vmCChV4/wmtaNcaWMrElXMtbdVSoCDJTBH6Sd4vMnortc1fyU2DbJk3U33Y1B9h11UP9pj9/3H@Yxfg)

Comment: 4 answers so far, and this is the only one that meets all criteria of the challenge.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 34 bytes

```
Oh!8W:q7W/YP**Y,XstX:X>|a?1M/127*k
```

Try at [MATL online!](https://matl.io/?code=Oh%218W%3Aq7W%2FYP%2a%2aY%2CXstX%3AX%3E%7Ca%3F1M%2F127%2ak&inputs=%5B1%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C5%2C8%2C13%2C21%2C34%5D&version=20.0.0). Or add code `XG` to [see a plot](https://matl.io/?code=Oh%218W%3Aq7W%2FYP%2a%2aY%2CXstX%3AX%3E%7Ca%3F1M%2F127%2akXG&inputs=%5B1%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C5%2C8%2C13%2C21%2C34%5D&version=20.0.0).

Comment: This is good, but see the IMPORTANT! addendum I added.

Comment: @Octopus Thanks, corrected now

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 75 bytes

```
(m=MaxValue[f=Tr[Sin[x/128Pi#]&/@#],x]+.1^9;Round[127f/m]~Table~{x,0,255})&
```

Try the code online at https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com.

Explanation:

```
            f=Tr[Sin[x/128Pi#]&/@#]                                         Define expression f contains variable x equal to the frequency
                                                                               as x runs from 0 to 256 (x/128Pi runs from 0 to 2Pi)
 m=MaxValue[                       ,x]                                      Find the maximum of f
                                      +.1^9                                 Avoid case of empty list when m=0
                                            Round[127f/m]                   Normalize value of f to correct range
                                                         ~Table~{x,0,255}   and make a table of the value.
```

Notes:

1. Using `MaxValue` instead of `NMaxValue` may have some symbolic issues, which is displayed as warning.
2. It can be proved that the function have `MaxValue + MinValue == 0`, so it is not necessary to calculate `MinValue`.
3. To run the code, put `[{1,3}]` for example after the code for input `{1,3}` and press `Shift+Enter` on Wolfram Sandbox.
4. Although the code produce exact result, it is not mathematically correct due to the bad way of handle empty input case. This version (**78 bytes**) is better.

---

```
(m=MaxValue[f=Tr[Sin[x/128Pi#]&/@#],x];Round[127f/m]~Table~{x,0,255}/.0/0->0)&
```

or (**80 bytes**)

```
(m=MaxValue[f=Tr[Sin[x/128Pi#]&/@#],x];If[m<1,0,Round[127f/m]]~Table~{x,0,255})&
```

This works because it can be proven that the maximum is at least 1 for all non-empty input.

Comment: Please do post an online IDE link

Comment: ...how do we call the function?

Comment: I'm with John. I can't figure out how to use the wolfram sandbox. Please tell us what to paste in (including an input sample) and what to do to make it go.

Comment: Does this handle empty input correctly? It should produce an array of zeros

Comment: The format I see output in the sandbox isn't the format asked for in the challenge, unless I did something wrong?

Comment: @Octopus The format looks fine to me.

Comment: The output of this is sometimes off from the test cases by `1`. Is this a rounding error, and if so, is that allowed?

Comment: [this is what i see in wolfram](http://exp.goocto.com/codegolf/img/wolfram_output.png)

Comment: @Octopus You pasted the "or" as part of the code. user202729 gave two different options for pasting in his comment.

Comment: [still](http://exp.goocto.com/codegolf/img/wolfram_output2.png)

Comment: Here is what I see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bB3cy.png

Answer (score 1):

## TI-BASIC, <s>47</s> <s>41</s> 48 bytes

*-6 thanks to @Octopus*

*+7 for handling `0`*

```
:Prompt Y                         //Get list of inputs, 3 bytes
:"sum(sin(XʟY→Y₁                  //Store sum of sines function to Y₁, 10 bytes
:Y₁(128ֿ¹πseq(B,B,0,255           //Use the function to compute the values at 256 points, 20 bytes
:iPart(127Ans/max({1ᴇ~9,max(Ans   //Normalize values and round, 8 bytes
```

This will not work for empty input, since **TI-BASIC** will never accept empty input ([see here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/118906/67881)).

**GIF:**

[image]

Comment: How does this take input then? What if I give it `[]` or `0`?

Comment: I'll add a .gif.

Comment: If you give it a list with with a zero `{0}`, it'll work...

Comment: I think you'll find that since the signals are always symmetrical, finding just the max is sufficient in the last line

Comment: @Octopus K, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 101 bytes

```
{my @w=[Z+] |(0 xx 256 xx 2),|.map:
(^256 »/»(128/π/*))».sin;(@w »*»(127/(@w.max||1)))».floor}
```

The frequencies are taken from the single list passed to this anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 102 bytes

```ruby
->r{(o=(0..255).map{|i|r.sum{|n|Math::sin(0.024544*i*n)}}).map{|f|(f*127/[1,*o].map(&:abs).max).to_i}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VjtTiPHEv3PU4yIlLCrbtLf3YNE3iD3BchqBRuTtZQAAqNkA372vedU1djG2ntfIJE99nxUV1edOvVhPz7ffPl6e/nV//T4cnZ/eRbOz1Ot787/uH54eV2/Pp4/Pf/x8nr3@vP15vPFxdP6DhIhlVrK@/X7u3fbrYnevp7dvo@p/3gV3fv7D7x59v3F9c0Tn//17nxz/3G93X59eN48Taf/ud@sLqb7u2nzefW0mjarJ9xdb354mn5dPz38fv1lfffb9Mvp5vF59cvptL6l3HT/vMHq6fJyWv31sPq0Wf3qpns8ePxzTR2QwEZQcHu7elzdfVqdn568nFx9mC5/mq6C@/f1D359cCcnV0mocAIuNBeTi8Ol4nJwubmSXBmuFldn16rrwfXqRnADn7Obi5uHiwFrQsWBc66PBUfHMUNdxJFx4F6CTGp29IPzas@zynOdrC@qj3pFf@J22BRbDzGji0kwDObBSJgKg2E2jKfCQXca/PTNeZx63PF44PHcQ8xD2mORx1oPFR6aPBR66PVQ7we/cR97emztaYKnLZ5G@Sg6YaanvZ6Ge3rg6YqnT57OeXq5fPS3l3Unl5e1okX1lWUP2U33TWoKTaJpw0ztZjpdoCt0ia7RRbpKl2WjoVAQln/D/c8Jt2R6dHmX60CrSeQB4exKJ6ItujYk5tGN7uasAUegAgPEYCEwAnQ4CHT7xlGPAox7EdcR60I7Cm5xfXYd24N1ZQkubCq0LFeJL2wVrtIArHXd4amLB8UMzuEerBZWVyF24kJyu4qTotboLdt12XqUY3o3tVQsbkfU/l@0XigdFCFBKipyQYAEnAAV0AJgwAyw6WcXJ5MwuCEq5CFi1oy6jCfiCzGJMRZ5rFXK4hwKPfQaXUmqIFQSZpFASoDwlqT/n59H1OSDyHuRWkL7FivxDRx9p4VMrHLASlpf1AuEQZlJ7yxBxUrqw3JIQgDXB2HFBW8VeTxbYldL7qS6JMGrIWV77pLcbOpm4yjfTPK2OKiutm/k91FqH33sszossGsA4hKUYHFivBg3xo9xZDwZV0GrG1LJ8he6h@Yu@ASKZGE3eQWiI1dR8KqkAu7uchurWyanYyBz056hVBGQ/BBArc9Mj8i0IdKZqdOWboCM6VJcIdQd2Y8sgUzQ8LDSMkU0z6K9LUHZWpLFLkpqVtabKOZXZ66gxuD@IpcWUSQmDQkiHyXV30hlfmq6NzwbggN6104mL@9FrIpg3wulhVL6TrvqUeW1lyKHlveemkBOXvlQrglBu5zUA9Esr/hGcAiTxyJ@IJt2knVH@GhHkMsmShSqN9LDxIrlB4@s94YI6JplRVONu1SK@2OXltpKFZ4gdg7dQCRJ1Wztph8kt9GWLNYMLmoJ8wSU82CeH5J0Yel6mj1SjOTBrDnaqD4J/RnFvlAIfNw3MqTMsHorLNduNRoHBbTEPITLTU7kPM1GZ2ZSYZNAvhQoqsyIjDvMBUVntkLV9ToZDNGmCrbcFqzgNcWiUyMqUGsyrQSq1taO59GmEK4n6tQfLGjJvnmPcFX9ljJ08JzyXMf1UuyS6o3iU5EtuXGjETS@q120T4qh2Z1t32yEEH@7@TvLdRYoCmEhOFJYUjqALhJMwqvYNjuHeoA/mnY/6YpNIoRAIVxB69zY1UitoEv3Gk3nGjFyGLGandu1ABePgElaNwv1V@VaNsCyFBTBg7NmkMzN9AEw0Nwgo0ejD4YBm0hrNmYFVatlC2hzUi50lWQKe0S4BVCr/OTUsEMqCFJDZpBEDUuuFlMv2zTdFttL7YU9nFPEwiy7ZKkT9EVoFqVQSq0L6iydFueDNZF0BFI09tQDQNv@WhhdNQjatrSpdYsVg1a6TZNRapbU9kwy5LLLypoY7BljVbB5p2cOWrPc7@IV3euciWIocmC6rTruSSp2Ri3ar4LKpwCooh0MGRK5n1CeDaU0USSzaZclQ/fQbWR7YAlo@HgwPll@PLArGixaQZPkrUy90i1hdubGHI4z31WKhLRNfDBMMzdA@05aIQlWkkof5R5xS5a4QxM7Gn8Zspq0JtYoCQhu9G5TdyFY1N2FoToldya2ToxkYrUxkpt3ywzpE3AEaJLWMuVH6xZRyUByyERJC6pU5yZsniUB8n7mJJ1YYJZ5VBKjH0x7UFq7zjGS06HYtNO7rIRT8A0uwtMsVYNpgkgMyQttNknLqgQksa3LHbFw6CRHmsa8aycCXdYmIUfUBBp5GYXjzg6dORlcGVb84k2zJMnWBLt6S0x6tp1ZOi1Hx@4XmlQsLuEgV5q6UKygFo2lTMDDsGn6201/1emPvKibFKv1rMcMhIoV@6B@gi3VOyjoBHlONnbn/Q@CmRPCrM8r2@b2fHX96fP08rpxq9dJ/2L87mWzvZi@e7m92ny4vFxN948TT8//Xj@crew/y2t383rtb7b8h/LjzZfl/0p8bE@3X/8L)

I know this is a slightly old one, but it looked like fun. The margin of error (for the given tests, anyway) is within ±1.