# What's my middle name?

Tags: code-golf, string

> **Note:** The winning answer will be selected on **4/12/17** the current winner is [Jolf, 1 byte](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115323/58826).

I'm surprised that we haven't had a what's my middle name challenge on this site yet. I did alot of searching but found nothing. If this is a dup, please flag it as such.

### Your challenge

Parse a string that looks like `Jo Jean Smith` and return `Jean`.

### Test cases

```
Input: Samantha Vee Hills
Output: Vee

Input: Bob Dillinger
Output: (empty string or newline)

Input: John Jacob Jingleheimer Schmidt
Output: Jacob Jingleheimer

Input: Jose Mario Carasco-Williams
Output: Mario

Input: James Alfred Van Allen
Output: Alfred Van
```

(That last one is incorrect technically, but fixing that  would be too hard.)

### Notes:

- Names will always have at least 2 space-separated parts, with unlimited middle names between them or can be a list/array of strings.
- Names may contain the alphabet (case-insensitive) and - (`0x2d`)
- You may output a trailing newline.
- You may require input to have a trailing newline.
- Input from STDIN, a function parameter, or command-line argument is allowed, but hard-coding it in is not allowed.
- Standard loopholes forbidden.
- Output may be function return value, STDOUT, STDERR, etc.
- Trailing spaces/newlines/tabs in the output are allowed.
- Any questions? Comment below!

**This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest anwser in bytes wins!**

Comment: Can input be taken in as list?

Comment: @AnthonyPham yes.

Comment: Can the output be a list of strings?

Comment: If other formats than a space-separated string are allowed, please edit that into the specification.

Comment: @programmer5000: if the input can be a list of strings, how about the output? Is `["John", "Jacob", "Jingleheimer", "Schmidt"]` -> `["Jacob", "Jingleheimer"]` a valid solution?

Comment: Are leading spaces allowed?

Comment: May we assume that all names are unique?

Comment: @Adám no, you can't.

Comment: @nimi yes, you can.

Comment: Requested test case: James Alfred van Allen

Comment: @Adám All names will be capitalized.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `That last one is incorrect technically, but fixing that would be too hard.`? If it's incorrect, why include it?

Comment: @DJ Because "Van" isn't his middle name, it's part of his last name. A particularly vexing case is David Lloyd George, whose first name is David and last name is Lloyd George. Any attempt to parse real people's names like this is doomed. In fact, you can't even tell what the first and last names are (think Li Shi).

Comment: Can we have leading spaces?

Comment: What are 'Standard loopholes' ?

Comment: @2501 https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default/

Comment: *You may output a trailing newline.* What is a trailing newline? A newline at the end of each word, or a newline at the end of the entire output?

Comment: @2501 At the end of the entire output.

Comment: @programmer5000 Thanks, I though so.

Comment: @programmer5000 - current leader is Jolf at one byte!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Jolf, 1 byte

```
€
```

Gets the inside of the input. [Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=4oKs&input=WyJKb25hdGhhbiIsICJWYW4iLCAiQWxsZW4iXQ)

Comment: Can't seem to get the example running - nothing seems to happen when I click any of the buttons. Using Chrome 57.0.2987.133

Comment: @YiminRong I can only assure it to work on firefox.

Answer (score 44):

## [Ohm](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), 2 bytes (CP437)

Accepts and returns a list of strings.

```
()
```

Explanation:

```
()   Main wire, arguments: a

(    Remove the first element of a
 )   ...and then the last element of that
     Implicit output
```

Comment: The right tool for the job I guess

Answer (score 14):

## Vim, <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
dW$BD
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@58SruLk8v@/V35GnoJXYnJ@koJXZl56TmpGamZuapFCcHJGbmZKCQA)

(outputs with a trailing space)

Since Vim is reverse-compatible with V, I have included a TIO link for V.

#### Explanation

```
dW                      " Delete up to the next word (removes the first name)
$                       " Go to the end of the line
B                       " Go back one word
D                       " Delete it
```

Comment: Drat, you beat me to it. `dWWD` saves you one byte.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem That only works for exactly one middle name.

Comment: What's the difference between dW and dw?

Comment: @DuncanXSimpson `dW` deletes until whitespace. `dw` deletes until non-word characters.

Answer (score 14):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/), 24 bytes

```python
lambda n:n.split()[1:-1]
```

[Try it online string input!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#y7GN@Z@TmJuUkqiQZ5WnV1yQk1mioRltaKVrGPu/oCgzr0QhRyMzr6AUKKr5Xyk4MTcxryQjUSEsNVXBIzMnp1gJAA)

Input Format: **string**

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 16 bytes

```python
lambda n:n[1:-1]
```

[Try it online list input!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#y7GN@Z@TmJuUkqiQZ5UXbWilaxj7v6AoM69EIUcjM6@gtERDU/N/tFJwYm5iXklGopKOUlhqKpD0yMzJKVaKBQA)

Input Format: **List**

Comment: You should edit the title with `Python` instead of `Python 2`, because it works for `Python 3` as well, was just about to post that.

Comment: @L3viathan since OP hasn't mentioned the output format `must be a string`, and since the input format is allowed to be a list, print a list cannot be considered as a wrong result!

Comment: According to the comments on the question, you can both input and output a list of strings. Save a bunch of bytes `lambda n:n[1:-1]`

Comment: Since you can read from STDIN, can replace the lambda with `input()` (Python 3 only)

Comment: You are right. Thanks. I've added the edits!

Answer (score 13):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 133 bytes

```
{{}((((()()()()){}){}){}[{}](<()>)){{}{}(<(())>)}{}}{}{({}<>)<>}<>{{}((((()()()()){}){}){}[{}](<()>)){{}{}(<(())>)}{}}{}{({}<>)<>}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@19dXasBApoQqFldC0HR1bWxGjYamnZAoepaoCIboBogD8gEomqN6lobO00bOyBJuQn//3vlZ@QpeCUm5ycpeGXmpeekZqRm5qYWKQQnZ@RmppT8100GAA)

132 bytes of code, plus 1 byte for the `-c` flag which allows ASCII input and output.

Unfortunately, this contains lots of duplicated code, but it would be really difficult to reuse. I'll look into it later. Here's an explanation:

```
#While True
{
    #Pop
    {}

    #Not equals 32
    ((((()()()()){}){}){}[{}](<()>)){{}{}(<(())>)}{}

#Endwhile
}

#Pop the 0
{}

#Reverse Stack
{({}<>)<>}<>

#While True
{
    #Pop
    {}

    #Not equals 32
    ((((()()()()){}){}){}[{}](<()>)){{}{}(<(())>)}{}

#Endwhile
}

#Pop the 0
{}

#Reverse Stack
{({}<>)<>}<>
```

Comment: 86 bytes when you remove the comments. I added the first two and the last line. [TIO](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#NU49C8IwEN3zKw6y5AZBdC3ZXDqIWMGhdKjtYYr90DbVIeS3x0ut98W7d/DeBaVQIQqnnM8VFokAkFfTtASXcSbeHHcMeRqeK3T@zx0HC/Say3aC/W4lVQz8JTr/q9z5QiUKNVPOO8@Yrxr9oiUPff2JpoyXnb3AGoKtWN3kmd40TgSZLatHZPnhRGOieYpFJ4R0MD2kZTXcIG36e0uGmo5GyCrTNbUNm@oL)

Comment: @riley Cool solution. Feel free to post it yourself!

Answer (score 11):

### Haskell, <s>23</s>, <s>17</s> 9 bytes

```
init.tail
```

Takes and returns a list of strings. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@59mm5mXWaJXkpiZ8z83MTNPwVahoCgzr0RBRSFNIVrJKz8jT0lHQckrMTk/CczIzEvPSc1IzcxNLQLxg5MzcjNTSpRi/wMA)

Drop first string, drop last string.

Edit: @Generic Display Name noted, that the input can be a list of strings, which saved 6 bytes.

Edit II: return list of strings instead of a single string

Comment: It looks like input as a list is allowed, so drop the words for -5 bytes

Comment: @GenericDisplayName: Oh, didn't notice. Thanks!

Comment: My Ohm answer and the Mathematica answer both output lists of strings as well, so you could probably drop `unwords.` for -8 bytes.

Comment: @NickClifford: yes, I saw that myself and asked the OP for clarification.

Answer (score 11):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
¦¨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@39o2aEV//9Hq3vlZ@Sp66h7JSbnJ4HozLz0nNSM1Mzc1CIgNzg5IzczpUQ9FgA)

If outputting a list of middle names isn't allowed, I'll change it.

Answer (score 10):

### Mathematica, 10 bytes

```
Rest@*Most
```

An unnamed function that accepts and returns a list of strings.

`Rest` discards the the last element, `Most` discards the first element, `@*` is function composition. Swapping `Rest` and `Most` or using right-composition `/*` instead would also work. This beats indexing via `#[[2;;-2]]&` by one byte.

Answer (score 9):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 86 bytes

```
(()()){({}[()]<{{}((((()()()()){}){}){}[{}](<()>)){{}{}(<(())>)}{}}{}{({}<>)<>}<>>)}{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#JYsxCsAgDEWv4pgMvUHwAK4dxaG1UoWqULqFnN3GNvl8fj4vAwABkYHFAwZiFpiD/yLLL88SgACtViwKkTJ6aVTNd7JIVv3rxnA9N@O22HfjSjuvlFOp6TZrzLUcz1jiCw)

Most of this code comes from [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/114942/57100). If you like my solution you should upvote that one as well.

```
#Push 2
(()())

#Loop twice
{({}[()]<

  #While not a space
  {
      #Pop
      {}

      #Not equals 32
      ((((()()()()){}){}){}[{}](<()>)){{}{}(<(())>)}{}

  #Endwhile
  }

  #Pop the 0
  {}

  #Reverse Stack
  {({}<>)<>}<>

#End loop twice
>)}{}
```

Comment: Well done! I didn't think about holding a counter for pushing later, so I spent too long thinking about how to loop across different stacks.

Answer (score 7):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <s>17</s> 10 bytes

*Saved 7 bytes thanks to @steve!*

```
$NF=$1=x;1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/awk#@6/i52arYmhbYW34/3@iQpJCskIKAA)

Explanation:

```
$NF=    set last word to
$1=     set first word to
x       an empty variable, ie empty string
1       default action, ie print everything
```

Comment: Can be shaved down to 11 bytes, `$NF=$1="";1`

Comment: Or 10 using `$NF=$1=x;1`

Comment: @steve what does `1` do? I'm not so good at AWK :)

Comment: 1 just means take the default action, that is, to print $0.

Answer (score 7):

## Java 7, 74 bytes

```
String f(String s){return s.substring(s.indexOf(' '),s.lastIndexOf(' '));}
```

## Java 8, 49 bytes

```
s->s.substring(s.indexOf(' '),s.lastIndexOf(' '))
```

Function which identifies the first occurrence of the space character and the last one and extracts the middle. The resulting string is prefixed by a space character (at the time of the posting, OP hasn't clarified if leading spaces are allowed), which can be eliminated by adding `.trim()` to the code for an extra cost of 7 bytes.

Compared to C#, Java has the advantage of specifying the end index instead of sub-string length, which brings down the byte count.

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript (ES6), 22 bytes

Takes and outputs an array of strings.

```js
([_,...a])=>a.pop()&&a
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

([_,...a])=>a.pop()&&a

console.log(f(["Samantha", "Vee", "Hills"]))
console.log(f(["Bob", "Dillinger"]))
console.log(f(["John", "Jacob", "Jingleheimer", "Schmidt"]))
console.log(f(["Jose", "Mario", "Carasco-Williams"]))
```

#### String version (27 bytes)

Takes and outputs a string. The output string is either a single space if no middle name was found, or the middle names with leading and trailing spaces.

```js
s=>(/ .* /.exec(s)||' ')[0]
```

```js
let f =

s=>(/ .* /.exec(s)||' ')[0]

console.log(f("Samantha Vee Hills"))
console.log(f("Bob Dillinger"))
console.log(f("John Jacob Jingleheimer Schmidt"))
console.log(f("Jose Mario Carasco-Williams"))
```

Comment: `/./.exec.bind(/ .* /)` seems to mimic #2, except `null` for none

Answer (score 5):

## [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/), 19 bytes

```
{it.split()[1..-2]}
```

Explanation:

```
{        
 it                  all closures have an implicit argument called "it"
   .split()          splits by spaces by default. Returns an array of words
           [1..-2]   take the whole array from the second index (1) to the penultimate index (-2). Implicitly return
                  }
```

A closure / anonymous function

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Can you take a list of strings as input to skip the `.split()`?

Comment: Martin Ender Yes, if you assume that the input will always be a list of strings then {it[1..-2]} would work.

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, 37 Bytes

```
<?=join(" ",array_slice($argv,2,-1));
```

-4 bytes for an output as array

```
print_r(array_slice($argv,2,-1));
```

### PHP, 42 Bytes

```
echo trim(trim($argn,join(range("!",z))));
```

### PHP, 50 Bytes

```
echo preg_filter("#(^[^\s]+ |[^\s]+$)#","",$argn);
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <strike>27</strike> 18 bytes

Need to run with `-n` option.

```perl
/ (.+) /&&print$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl5#@6@voKGnramgr6ZWUJSZV6Ji@P@/V35GnoJXYnJ@koJXZl56TmpGamZuapFCcHJGbmZKyb/8gpLM/Lzi/7p5AA)

Wanted to do something similar in sed first, but, unfortunately, it doesn't support non-greedy quantifier. <strike>It is needed in case middle name is more than one word.</strike>

**Edit**

-9 bytes thanks to **Dada**.

Non-greedy quantifier is not needed anymore, among with some other things.

Comment: `/ (.+) /&&print$1` should be sorter. Great to see some new people golfing with Perl!

Comment: @Dada Thanks for the tip! It's actually my first time ever writing in Perl. Do you know why `print if s| (.+) |\1|` doesn't work? To me it looks similar to what you wrote.

Comment: `print if s| (.+) |\1|` replaces the middle part with... the middle part! (minus the spaces before and after), so it doesn't work. On the other side, what I suggested only *matches* the middle part and print only it (`$1`).

Comment: Nice! You can get this down using `-p` too and using `x` instead of `&&`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lbFsEJfQUNPW1NB//9/r/yMPAWvxOT8JAWvzLz0nNSM1Mzc1CKF4OSM3MyUkn/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULAA)

Answer (score 4):

## sed, <s>21</s> <s>19</s>  <s>17</s>  15 bytes + `-E`

new:

*idea thanks to @user41805*

*-2 thanks to @xigoi*

*-2 thanks to @ user41805*

```
s/^\S+ |\S+$//g
```

old:

*-1 thanks to @user41805*

```
s/\S+ ((.+ )*).+/\1/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcvNCkIhEIbhvVcxi3YhXkN/EEIr4bRpM@l0FHQ8OHb7mbV7eD8@oaBXfo8h5uH2YIz6Y2fMGA4Lco8ICxFcU86ijvUJ56nEKzVla2Sw6Ge0s2SKlAo1cD6WFPrcheCGLVU4YUPxVd9/ZyyiLBYSOORXowAL8mQm/tStp8oy9OUL/0A)

Comment: Is it possible for you to edit in a link to an online interpreter, such as [Try it online!](https://tio.run/#sed-gnu), so that others can run your program?

Comment: @ChartZBelatedly Is that better?

Comment: `[^ ]` can become `\S`. But I think if you split your program into two substitutions you can save some bytes.

Comment: @user41805 I tried that and it worked!:) I've already updated my answer

Comment: I think the second substitution should be `s/ ?\S+$//` instead for it to work on 'Bob Dillinger'. But now, you should be able to combine these two substitutions with a `|`.

Comment: Fixed and two bytes shorter: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcvNCkIhEIbhvVcxi3YhXkN/EEIr4bRpM@l0FHQ8OHb7mbV7eD8@oaBXfo8h5uH2YIz6Y2fMGA4Lco8ICxFcU86ijvUJ56nEKzVla2Sw6Ge0s2SKlAo1cD6WFPrcheCGLVU4YUPxVd9/ZyyiLBYSOORXowAL8mQm/tStp8oy9OUL "sed – Try It Online")

Comment: Combining them gives two bytes less `s/^\S+ |\S+$//g`.

Answer (score 3):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 11 bytes

```
^\S+ |\S+$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#U9VwT/gfFxOsrVADJFS4/v8PTsxNzCvJSFQIS01V8MjMySnmcspPUnABsjLz0lOLuLzyM/IUvBKTgYJeQJGc1IzUzNzUIoXg5IzczJQSoHxxqoJvYlFmvoJzYlFicXK@bjhIc2JuMQA)

Matches the first word (including the space after it) and the last word, and removes both of them.

If I/O can be a linefeed-separated list, it can be done in 8 bytes instead:

```
A1`
G-2`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#FYs7CsMwEAV7neI1hjQq4hvkAzECVwKnSaGNslgL@oDk@ytyN8ww08U69NvVqZeeXf9khW4pUT4CYWPGIjE2dS9fPAdJ3rkqU0KGIT@kGSZyYElcYX1I8jtGb4yVqhQ8qFLzRb/PmVL7Aw)

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript (ES6) <s>49</s> 16 bytes

### **Edit:**

```
a=>a.slice(1,-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/javascript-node#S7P9X2FrV6FXnJOZnKphqKNrqPk/OT@vOD8nVS8nP10jTSNaKTgxNzGvJCNRSUdBKSw1FUR5ZObkFCvFampyoSt2yk8CKXABKsjMS08twqrIKz8jD6TKKzEZotwLqDYnNSM1MxeoA8gPTs7IzUwpwaG5GOwG38SizHwQwzmxKLE4OV83HGRnYi7YXf8B)

**ungolfed:**

```
function(name) {
  return a.slice(1, -1); //start at the second item and end at the second to last item
};
```

I forgot some of the simple properties of [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), and that the input can be an array. Thanks to @Neil and @fəˈnɛtɪk I was able to remove 27 bytes. Still not really competing.

### **Original:**

This isn't really competing but here's a Javascript solution:

```
a=>{a=a.split(' ');return a.slice(1, a.length-1)}
```

This creates an anonymous function equal to:

```
function(name) {
  let name = name.split(' '); //first middle last -> [first, middle, last]
  return name.slice(1, name.length - 1); //get the second item to the second to last item in the array.
}
```

#### How I golfed it

This is a pretty simple golf. I turned the function into an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). Then I "minified" the code. This included renaming `name` into a single character(`a` in this case) and removing the `let` decloration of the variable.

#### Snippet

```js
var a=b=>b.slice(1,-1)

//example code

let form = document.querySelector('#form'),
    input = document.querySelector('#input'),
    result = document.querySelector('#result');

form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  let value = input.value.split` `;
  result.textContent = a(value).join(' ');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form id="form">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input id="input" class="form-control" />
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<p id="result"></p>
```

Hope this helps anyone who is stuck on the challenge.

Comment: The `length -` is unnecessary, as `slice` already accepts negative lengths as being relative to the end. This means that you no longer need the intermediate variable, so you can turn your arrow function from a block into an expression.

Comment: Actually the way it works is that `-1` is the last but one that you need here.

Comment: It is also slice(1,-1). slice(1,-2) removes two from the end.

Comment: You can also assume that you were passed an array to begin with, which lets you just perform slice and you are done.

Comment: I'm 99% sure that was changed since I started it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn), [4 bytes](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki/Carn)

```
†Û⁺%
```

[Try it!](https://zippymagician.github.io/Arn?code=LnsufQ==&input=U2FtYW50aGEgVmVlIEhpbGxzCkJvYiBEaWxsaW5nZXIKSm9obiBKYWNvYiBKaW5nbGVoZWltZXIgU2NobWlkdApKb3NlIE1hcmlvIENhcmFzY28tV2lsbGlhbXM=)

## Explained

Unpacked: `.{.}`

```
_ Variable initialized to STDIN; implied
  .{ Take
    .} Then drop
         Output implicit
```

Strings are split on spaces if any or ever character if there are non (when casted to an array).

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s><sup>6</sup></s> 4 bytes

```
;htw
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/3zqjpPz///9e@Rl5Cl6JyflJCl6Zeek5qRmpmbmpRQrByRm5mSklAA)

-2 bytes from Zgarb.

Comment: @JoKing like you said earlier, `h` and `t` return a list of strings, so something strange happens when `w` is applied.

Comment: Nah, the issue was that the first `w` was being interpreted as `words`, and the second as `uwpshw`, which makes sense as the type system is greedy

Comment: Use `;` to "format" the output instead of `J`

Answer (score 2):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), 9 bytes

```
{_[1:-1]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/roda#JYuxCsIwGIRn8xRHZot0VVzUQQqdCjq0pfzGvybQJJLUqfbZa4rDwd13d5aMw4T@2CxTV@f7LG/nZTOhdmR5JyFbfNEnvT9Ro9siocM/yMZJzOh9wDoW81KRJTdqwo0ZVzMMUZz8A5fkjHtxEIXXDgWpBItEBtZsLAdUSlvzHFMfGSUF43GmQFH57L6eycYf)

Not a very interesting solution. Takes a list from the stream and returns the middle names.

21 bytes and I/O:

```
{[(_/" ")[1:-1]&" "]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/roda#FYu9CsJAEAZr7yk@UogWQdIKNmohAauAFjGENW68hfuRu3Qxz36e3TDDWBKHGePhkeZ20@8KFNu22pdVt87YLWk14otPEDehV0tqyJKbNOHGjIsYE9XRP3HOJO7NQdVeO9Q0ZFlnY1izWA5oBm3lNeUeGVcK4nGiQHHw5f0/k40/)

This uses `/` (split) and `&` (join).

Answer (score 2):

## Matlab, <s>81</s>, <s>79</s>, <s>78</s>, 55 Bytes

```
function x=a(s)
s=strsplit(s);x=strjoin(s(2:end-1));end
```

Takes in an input string, `s`, is split (by the default delimiter, whitespace char) into a cell array, from which the middle element is accessed. Then the middle elements are concatenated, or an empty string is returned.

Edit: thanks to Luis Mendo for saving 3 bytes!

Edit 2: Better solution from Ankit!

Comment: I am not a smart man! edited.

Comment: You can't use `nnz` on a cell array, but I did the other two changes :)

Comment: Suggested Edit by [Ankit](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67708/ankit), who doesn't have enough rep to comment. (55 bytes): `function x=a(s) s=strsplit(s);x=strjoin(s(2:end-1));end`

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
ḊṖ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/9wR9fDndP@//@v7pWfkaeuo@6VmJyfBKIz89JzUjNSM3NTi4Dc4OSM3MyUEnUA)

This works as a non-inline link (i.e. function), not a full program.

`'John','Jacob','Jingleheimer','Schmidt'` → `'Jacob','Jingleheimer'`

As a full program, it would be 3 bytes: `ḊṖK`, which prints a space-separated middle name.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 2 bytes

```
Pt
```

[Online interpreter](//pyth.herokuapp.com?code=Pt&input=%5B%27John%27%2C%27Jacob%27%2C%27Jingleheimer%27%2C%27Schmidt%27%5D)

Answer (score 2):

## C#, 67 bytes

```
s=>s.Substring(s.IndexOf(' ')+1,s.LastIndexOf(' ')-s.IndexOf(' '));
```

Anonymous function which identifies the first occurrence of the space character and the last one and extracts the middle. It also extracts a trailing space, which can be removed at the cost of 2 bytes.

Full program with test cases:

```
using System;

namespace WhatsMyMiddleName
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Func<string, string> f =
            s=>s.Substring(s.IndexOf(' ')+1,s.LastIndexOf(' ')-s.IndexOf(' '));

            Console.WriteLine(f("Jo Jean Smith"));          // "Jean"
            Console.WriteLine(f("Samantha Vee Hills"));     // "Vee"
            Console.WriteLine(f("Bob Dillinger"));          // ""
            Console.WriteLine(f("John Jacob Jingleheimer Schmidt"));// "Jacob Jingleheimer"
            Console.WriteLine(f("Jose Mario Carasco-Williams"));    // "Mario"
            Console.WriteLine(f("James Alfred Van Allen")); // "Alfred Van"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, <s>24</s> 13 bytes

```
p ARGV[1..-2]
```

*Saved 11 bytes thanks to Piccolo pointing out that array-like output is allowed.*

Takes the name as separate command line arguments, e.g.:

```
$ ruby script.rb John Jacob Jingleheimer Schmidt
```

or

```
$ ruby -e 'p ARGV[1..-2]' John Jacob Jingleheimer Schmidt
```

---

Previous code (outputs a proper string):

```
puts ARGV[1..-2].join" "
```

Comment: @Jordan Good idea - however with `$><<ARGV[1..-2].join" "` it complains about the `" "` being unexpected, so I'd have to add parentheses - which would add 1 byte in the end.

Comment: Ah, of course. My bad.

Comment: The original poster said that the output can be an array, so you can shave some characters off by just changing your code to ``puts ARGV[1..-2]``, just so you know.

Comment: @Piccolo Huh? I don't see that anywhere? If true; `p ARGV[1..-2]` for 13 bytes - just looks nothing like the output in OPs challenge

Comment: @Flambino http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/114927/whats-my-middle-name/114993?noredirect=1#comment280325_114927

Comment: @Piccolo Ah, in the comments - well, 13 bytes then! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 39 bytes

```
s.filterIndexed{i,j->i!=0&&i!=s.size-1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/kotlin#PY1PC4IwGMbP@SnWDrKBSl0lhY5J0MFPsNw7fWXO2BasxM9uq0OXh98Dzx/1NCQwV17R@VPrLZq@5qTaXKFQe7AXIyGAXDAb8xr31SFNo7rC4Rvy47qp2J8EGiZs70pytla8/jtLsntE8tqwwHR8uClGm3kwNCO0Ed18/0HMahgAJ7Bf33bDhNJTznmybh8)

i.e.

```
s.filterIndexed{ index, value -> index != 0 && index != (s.size - 1) }
```

Answer (score 2):

## VBA, 69 bytes

```
Sub m(n)
f=InStr(1,n," ")
Debug.?Mid(n,f+1,InStrRev(n," ")-f)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

## R, <s>30</s> <s>27</s> 22 bytes

Current solution due to user11599!

```
head(scan(,''),-1)[-1]
```

Takes input from stdin, returns each middle name as a separate string. Returns `character()` in the case of no middle name; that is, a vector of class `character` of length `0`.

**Explanation:**

Read stdin into a list of strings, separated by spaces

```
     scan(,'')
```

Remove the last element. `head` returns the first `n` elements of a list, with `n` defaulting to `6`. If `n` is `-1` it returns all but the last element.

```
head(scan(,''),-1)
```

Now, remove the first element of this list.

```
head(scan(,''),-1)[-1]
```

This yields the middle name(s).

Comment: Even shorter:  head(scan(,''),-1)[-1]      22 bytes.  Note that '' are two single quotes.

Comment: If you don't want each name quoted, use, at 27 bytes, cat(head(scan(,''),-1)[-1])

Comment: Explanation:  scan(,'') breaks the string into words, head(...,-1) drops the last word, head(...,-1)[-1] then drops the first word, cat() formats the output dropping the quotes.  For no middle name, result isn't perfect, it's character(0), the empty string.

Comment: @user11599 Wow, thanks! I had played around with `head()` and `tail()`, but I didn't know you could pass a negative number as the second argument. Nice!

Comment: Your use of scan(,'') inspired me.  I didn't think of approaching that way.

Answer (score 2):

### [Grime](https://github.com/iatorm/grime), 6 bytes

```
<\ 0\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/grime#@28To2AQo/D/f3pWeoZCWnpGmUJ6egYA)
Note the trailing space.

### Explanation

```
        Match a substring S that satisfies:
<       S is contained in a string of the form
 \      a space
   0    then S
    \   then another space.
```

This matches a substring that's surrounded by spaces.
By default, Grime prints the longest match it finds (without the spaces).
If no match exists, nothing is printed.

Answer (score 2):

### C, 42 bytes

```
f(char**b){for(;b[2];printf("%s ",*++b));}
```

The parameter is a NULL terminated array of pointers to char.

See it [work here](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#bZAxa8MwEIV3/4qHoCDZGUI7ql1Kh@I1kCV4kF05FkiykZ3J@Le7J9lpG@iBuNPjew/u1pY3nQp5Xou57QOX9eW5kkMwfmo5exrBDnlR1ELIZSUNThnPEScVrg0O2NzxN0JkcwaqpMFeKrxhBjspp/zUKUY4O2ud@qexdozTEQvkH5u/2977OpEfRBp/1eE/2t3psu98wkvV7MaSXFZ32rjNy05N58zX9JjzG5Zj2NMsEZ6ee6TigdLuhqgjJPVXvMReFLR8RLYDJJhTnKkg9oRYw20aORj7EZctfMnW9Rs).

The command line arguments [may also be used with the same function](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#JYuxCsMgFEV3v@IhFDRmaVf/wLVjyaBWo1A1qJ1Cvv01pnc658BFz2zQdZoM332pTJrXY5Fbjbl7Rm8N6DwJYTiXB54Nko6ZwSBdVwsz/N/DGnCyEzjn2eXiDhzkVbZvbwwoHWE4OQiiKiGj0rYYVDGvHxdcTK7i04YU3/0H).

### C, 51 bytes

```
main(a,b)char**b;{for(;b[3];printf("%s ",b++[2]));}
```

A full program. Input is done through command line arguments.

See it [work here](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#BcGxCoAgEADQXwkhUHOq0T9wbRQHzzQPUsPcom@/3iMqHiv3CkTIvksJ@k2tcw12c/ruWEfibH4mpmBZ7OqE0B@RabmS8aEBGaznFXPEEjvtIRc8xg8).

### C, 54 bytes

```
f(char**b){*strrchr(*b=strchr(*b,32),32)=0;*b+=!!**b;}
```

The parameter is an in/out parameter.

See it [work here](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#VY5Pa4QwEMXP9VO8FVo07mGpR@ul9FC8LvRi9xBtdhNIoozSi/jZ7cQspR2YP@T9ZvK2a9ZrSUJ0@SKmmajXlImu5jFOx/I5D1mfKtEV9eHAaLVuxs9w0vgMYZI4Ip6BpNs38mRJHsIDbHtBjfQsnfSzlvhQCu/G2imt7oSPxOvQ4Y0F42@KfkUXxWbQHo3smWkYsEor4xTh3GtnvmbGwbGX3QbGtgyLCyw785wOK/5Q14Gic8PUCRX3F5ShFwW7D8iy1x3O8DS25oL8fiLESLzOSvo4ffqUf/hHrMmabNsP).

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: I'm receiving the following error when compiling with Visual Studio 2012:error C2100: illegal indirection

Comment: @JohanduToit VS is not C11 or even C99 conforming. My code is. As practical proof, both gcc and clang compile a valid program.

Answer (score 2):

## **Golang**, <s>152</s> 81 bytes

```
import ."strings"
func f(x string)[]string{var k=Fields(x);return k[1:len(k)-1];}
```

It takes input as "Samantha Vee Hills" (with double quotes) and return the middle name to the stdout.

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/nexus/go#NY2xCoMwGIRn8xQ/gZYEWsG10rV0LAhdxCHYxIYkf20SiyA@u9Vqt7vvuLtW1EY0EpzQSLRrXz4CVS7SaTMpDdFrbAIlqsMaFOthJbysVjF8hAdzvmhpH4H1PPcydh7BlNnJSmSGH7MqH6dffzliHAaSLC3ctkgyf6ZFLVAxunvTA@yRr/A25/FPFUPOyTjRQjiB8SngLiVctbWBfgE)

Edit: @Dada, note that the "function as answer is allowed" shorten my code 71 bytes. a big thanks!

Comment: Welcome on the site.  Submitting a function as answer is allowed, so you could shorten your code by doing something like this: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/go#NY2xCoMwGIRn8xQ/gZYEWsG10rV0LAhdxCHYxIYkf20SiyA@u9Vqt7vvuLtW1EY0EpzQSLRrXz4CVS7SaTMpDdFrbAIlqsMaFOthJbysVjF8hAdzvmhpH4H1PPcydh7BlNnJSmSGH7MqH6dffzliHAaSLC3ctkgyf6ZFLVAxunvTA@yRr/A25/FPFUPOyTjRQjiB8SngLiVctbWBfgE "Go – TIO Nexus"). Have a look at the [Tips for Golfing in Go](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/41862/tips-for-golfing-in-go)!

Comment: thank you @Dada for tips and shorten my code. It was my first code entry.

Answer (score 2):

## Clojure, 43 bytes:

```clj
#(drop 1(butlast(read-string(str"("%")"))))
```

Here we read string as an [edn](https://github.com/edn-format/edn) data, then choosing its center.

## Or for stdout, 57 bytes:

```clj
#(apply pr-str(drop 1(butlast(read-string(str"("%")")))))
```

You can also check it [here](https://repl.it/@KlieiMomient/Code-Golf-Full-Name).

Comment: Is the space in `str "` necessary?

Comment: @JonathanFrech it leads to "RuntimeException Unmatched delimiter: )  clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException (Util.java:221)" without space

Comment: @JonathanFrech I add link to online Clojure REPL, so you can check it.
UPD: where it works... It's strange.

Comment: To me it looks like you changed it in your online REPL, did not change your post and said it would not work ... ([TIO](https://tio.run/##DckxDoAgDEDRq5AakzI4eAt3E/cqRDEVSCnnx/7lD@/i8naJA6ukrJxxTBikVLfi2ZWpKUqksDQ1v9EGCDN48NaAnT7K@pA7YnRbYm4G4wc)).

Answer (score 2):

## Powershell, 32 bytes

```powershell
''+($args|sls ' .+ '|% m*)|% t*m
```

Test script:

```powershell
$f = {
''+($args|sls ' .+ '|% m*)|% t*m
}

@(
    ,("Samantha Vee Hills"    ,"Vee")
    ,("Bob Dillinger"    ,"")
    ,("John Jacob Jingleheimer Schmidt"    ,"Jacob Jingleheimer")
    ,("Jose Mario Carasco-Williams"    ,"Mario")
    ,("James Alfred Van Allen"    ,"Alfred Van")
) | % {
    $name,$expected = $_
    $result = &$f $name
    "$($result-eq$expected): $expected"
}
```

Output:

```powershell
True: Vee
True:
True: Jacob Jingleheimer
True: Mario
True: Alfred Van
```

Answer (score 2):

## Brainfuck, 98 bytes

```
>+[,>++++[<-------->-]<]>++++[<++++++++>-]<[>,]++++[<-------->-]<[[-]++++[<-------->-]<]<[<]>>[.>]
```

### Explanation

```
>+[,>++++[<-------->-]<] Skip input until first space

>++++[<++++++++>-]< Store a Space char incase there is no middle name
[>,] Store input to a char array

++++[<-------->-]<[[-]++++[<-------->-]<] Goto the last space and zero the last space

<[<] Goto the start of the char array
>>[.>] Print the char array
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```factor
[ rest 1 head* ]
```

(-1 byte as `1 head*` is 1 byte shorter than `but-last`.)

### Explanation:

It's a quotation (anonymous function) that takes a sequence of strings as input and leaves a sequence of strings as output.

- `rest` Take all elements of a sequence but the first.
- `1 head*` Take all elements of a sequence but the last.

Answer (score 2):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 9 bytes

```
NF--,$1=a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fz01XV0fF0Dbx///g/NzUkozMvHQF15ziVIXwjNS85FQF3@SQjNSiVAA)

```
NF--,     - Cut out the last argument (also eval's to "true")
     $1=a - Blank out the first argument
```

Since there's always at least 2 input fields `NF--1` is always truthy, so the code prints `$0`.

In case the leading space isn't allowed (the question was asked in the comments under the initial posting but there was no response), then this is the shortest I've come up with.

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 15 bytes

```
NF-=sub($1FS,a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fz03Xtrg0SUPF0C1YJ1Hz/3/fIj2F4MwiBd/MlJSc1LzE3FQF32SfxOISEBMA)

```
    sub($1FS,a)  - Remove the first field, plus space from the input
NF-=             - Decrement "NF" by one (the return from "sub")
```

Comment: Nice `NF--` trick, but this outputs with one leading space, which I don't think is allowed.

Comment: I couldn't tell if the leading space was allowed or not.  Several people asked the in the comments about the question, but there was no response from the person who submitted it.  I saw a couple others that seems to have a leading space though, so I assumed it was ok?

Comment: Then out of curiousity, because I don't know much awk, how would you golfily fix this to remove the leading space? I've got https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fz01XV01NxchWiUNJxUhHxdA28f//4Pzc1JKMzLx0Bdec4lQA so far

Comment: Ha!  I've been pondering ways to get rid of the leading space too...  I'll post the one I came up with as an alternative in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$2\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 1.646 bytes

```
pq
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJwcSIsIltKb2huLEphY29iLEppbmdsZWhlaW1lcixTY2htaWR0XSJd)

```
pq
 q # Remove the tail
p  # Remove the head
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <del>42</del> <del>19</del> 16 Bytes

```
lambda n:n[1:-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/GqhH/2) Thanks to @Kritixi Lithos for saving 23 bytes! Thanks @math_junkie for saving 3 more bytes. For input, put each part of the name as a string within a list like so:

```
["Samantha", "Vee", "Hills"]
```

And yes, the OP has approved a list to be a valid input.

**Explanation**

```
lambda n:n[1:-1]    # Returns only the middle elements... pretty literal here
```

Comment: `print input()[1:-1]` is shorter

Comment: Spring slicing sure is tricky

Comment: `lambda n:n[1:-1]` is even shorter

Comment: I may have tried with a wrong input. But when I tried, with `Samantha Vee Hills` as input in repl.it link that you've shared, this just prints `amantha Vee Hill` which is definitely not the output required.

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran The program accepts a list and not a string

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran The input should be `["Samantha", "Vee", "Hills"]`

Comment: `Names will always have at least 2 space-separated parts` is the first point of the question right.

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran The OP said that the input can be a list.

Comment: Oh alright. That was a part of comment and didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>8</s> 6 bytes

```apl
¯1↓1↓⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/apl-dyalog#@@/4qG3CofWGj9omg/CjrkX/H/VNBYo5amiou2UWFZeoa2qo@ySCaE0uLFK@mSkpOalEK4KwDJHU/wcA)

This is a tacit train.

#### Explanation

When `↓` is a dyad, it returns all but the first/last *n* elements of its vector argument.

```apl
   1↓                  ⍝ Remove the first element in the 
     ⊢                 ⍝ right argument
¯1↓                    ⍝ and remove the last element
```

Answer (score 1):

## C++, 91 bytes

```
#import<list>
#import<string>
void f(std::list<std::string>&n){n.pop_front();n.pop_back();}
```

Takes input as a reference to a list of strings and modifies the list directly.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cpp-gcc#bY1BboQwDEX3OYUVpCqRqjkApByA7RxglAmhWCUxSkw3iLMzgaG7emH5@ft/7xWGmRKbCTO34o8yJ4zfrfgl7GFQmfu6Pi7MOV3qR9RrvM00P4ZEkZVu3vS07qfAtlcY3bT0HgxS8XgbWoGRIViMSotVQKn/s4F95q9VdjRG@Qmys46e51DUyY8eg08H390YsGe5NWfaoA6jvoCSsgsTZKjPQP3@Bo4WBmPKvjQJshHb/gI)

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <strike>31</strike> 19 bytes

```bash
echo ${@:2:$[$#-2]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@5@anJGvoFLtYGVkpRKtoqxrFFv7//9/r/yMvP9eicn5Sf@9MvPSc1IzUjNzU4v@Bydn5GamlAAA)

**Breakdown:**

Prints parameter expansion from second to second last element.

**Edit**

Removed commented code from breakdown section, since it's now just one line long.

-12 bytes thanks to **Neil**

Comment: Can you not just echo the expression in the first line directly?

Comment: @Neil How can I do that, if the result of the expression is not `$@`?

Comment: Surely `set --` assigns the result of the expression to `$@`?

Comment: @Neil Took me way too long to understand what you mean. This is embarrasing...

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>144</s> <s>139</s> <s>91</s> 86 bytes

```c
y,z;char*f(char*s){for(y=0;*++s-32;);for(;s[y];y++)z=s[y]-32?z:y;z[s]=0;return!!*s+s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxBa4QwFITP@iveLhSMUWi7t6ZSSqEH2Z562MPWQzZGfaBJybMtcdnfnkZPM8w3M6rslQrBF4tQg3R5l21C7NpZl/nqXuScU3l4FEysiaCzb4TnnC3VaiN5WZ68WM7UxLLT848zu11OnMQtoJlhkmiy1UjXqwLWe8ij/z037Jom8RQ2jFDBg4jyvDUFcI4sTZJvF2mX7e/oy@yLLtum2DAm0lsItR0M1FLZC9Ro@lEPGift4FMNE7ZzeDWt039wHK1v4aQv2oV3dDTDUdIc16ThQzq08CadJGXLE44jyon@AQ)

-48 bytes by learning C over the past year and a half since I first posted this

-7 bytes from [Jonathan Frech](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/114927/whats-my-middle-name/114991?noredirect=1#comment427200_114991)

A function that takes in a `char*` and outputs a `char*` corresponding to the (character after the) first space in the string, but also edits the string so that it's last space is replaced with `\0`.

Note: this function will segfault if given a string without a space in it.

Full program:

```c
y;z;char*f(char*s){y=0;while(*++s-32);while(s[y]){z=s[y]-32?z:y;y++;}s[z]=0;return s+!!*s;}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
	for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
		printf("%s\n",f(argv[i]));
}
```

Un-golfed:

```c
char *middle(char* name) {
	int index = 0, lastspace;
	while(name[0] != ' ') // move name pointer forward to the first space
		++name;
	while(name[index] != '\0') { // find the index in the (new) string of the last space
		if (name[index] == ' ') lastspace = index;
		index++;
	}
	name[lastspace] = '\0'; // Terminate the string at the last space
	if (name[0] == '\0') return name; // If the last space was the first space, return the empty string
	else return name + 1; // Else, return the new string
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVLNTsMwDD63T2Emoa3rEONcdkAIJCY4gbQD2yGk7mqpTaYkbCDEsxfH6yYGNyf@/uxEX6y17jpdKwfjlsqywVE8jMGoFjP4ShMyAciU@AEzmE6gUT74jdJYpMmuJsZH5Ot0BWczGMIwg8tLaO0WRQE2lvnooLJup1wJwUKoESpyPoDopEmS5xF7KiiWe9HllFW/om7Ft8LfByIjh5HBXQY@ODJrsJXcxZhHfargRHTWJz3OwqNJq4jgWOQ5l99pIqwjjJmSpohZXtC1ZFRA8evdVfjnfjSf7o1lGofh3RlZkYg9/E0NO@X/bmpyoMV7bDfhs7dNE2w8/haFHK5E@I4bJzze1YH13cW3bRWZUSyUW@sJ7L8C19vXVcbPzw8H0iYenjUJrgVZQJ5TxvvasFaoRoNzvzSDSf@HhE@rLCvYpZvb2sBcafsGczZusEZq@VM865rxobsxpeNYj439LGGBb@i6exn7kffBbJ7tSTmycKuc8tpeLKhpSLX@Bw)

Comment: [86 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYxBa4QwFITP@iveLhSMUWi7t6ZSSqEH2Z562MPWQzZGfaBJybMtcdnfnkZPM8w3M6rslQrBF4tQg3R5l21C7NpZl/nqXuScU3l4FEysiaCzb4TnnC3VaiN5WZ68WM7UxLLT848zu11OnMQtoJlhkmiy1UjXqwLWe8ij/z037Jom8RQ2jFDBg4jyvDUFcI4sTZJvF2mX7e/oy@yLLtum2DAm0lsItR0M1FLZC9Ro@lEPGift4FMNE7ZzeDWt039wHK1v4aQv2oV3dDTDUdIc16ThQzq08CadJGXLE44jyon@AQ).

Comment: [68 bytes](https://tio.run/##TYy9TsMwFIXn5CmuOsWJIxHYMAEhJIaoTAwdUIdrx0mulNjo2lBQ1Wc3aSamc3R@PlOPxqQ0FORiGcTZTMgltuR6@1MEeXcrqkaWuuV/iToxRVs0EqV@xCdd4/2NUJe0ImBBclcWII9GwhUH5eq/P47inGeDZ9hqghYatcrDtlRQVSTyLBuKbUxHIT@/Yih2O6HyS0qdnxx0aLyGjtw428nSYhnezbRQH9Oz69meYD/73x4OVltOr8Qhwh5DXN/BwhsyeXhBxmB8faB5JlzCHw "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 6 bytes

```
{1>W<}
```

Anonymous block that expects an array of strings on the stack, and leaves an array of strings after.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#K6z7X21oF25T@7@u4H@0kld@Rp6SgpJXYnJ@EojOzEvPSc1IzcxNLQJyg5MzcjNTSpRiAQ)

**Explanation**

```
1>    e# Slice the array after the first element
  W<  e# Slice the array before the last element
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 13 bytes

```
->s{s[1..-2]}
```

The author confirmed in comments that the input and output can be arrays.

Answer (score 1):

### REXX, 42 bytes

```
arg a
say delword(delword(a,words(a)),1,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, 3 bytes

```
Å¯J
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=xa9K&input=WyJTYW1hbnRoYSIsIlZlZSIsIkhpIl0=) or [run all test cases](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=xa9K&input=WwpbIlNhbWFudGhhIiwiVmVlIiwiSGkiXQpbIkJvYiIsIkRpbGxpbmdlciJdClsiSm9obiIsIkphY29iIiwiSmluZ2xlaGVpbWVyIiwiU2NobWlkdCJdClsiSm9zZSIsIk1hcmlvIiwiQ2FyYXNjby1XaWxsaWFtcyJdLFsiSmFtZXMiLCJBbGZyZWQiLCJWYW4iLCJBbGxlbiJdCl0KLW1S)

Comment: Alternative: `s1J`

Comment: Oh, [I posted an answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115160/61613) over a year ago. I'm gonna update it to `s1J` if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-s`, 8 bytes

```
@<@>Ya^s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P/fwcbBLjIxrvj///@6xf@98jPyFLwSk/OTFLwy89JzUjNSM3NTixSCkzNyM1NKAA)

-1 from DLosc.

Comment: [8 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P/fwcbBLjIxrvj///@6xf@98jPyFLwSk/OTFLwy89JzUjNSM3NTixSCkzNyM1NKAA), and you'll need the `-s` flag to handle cases with multiple middle names. If you take an array as input (using the `-x` flag--not available on TIO), you don't need the `^s` and can therefore drop the `Y`. Or, if it's okay to take each of the name parts as a separate command-line argument (which is what you'd have if you typed them space-separated on the command line), you can use `g` instead of `Ya^s`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm keeping the 8byte version for now.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-p040`, 13 bytes

```perl
$_ x=$.>1&/ /
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lXqHCVkXPzlBNX0H//3@v/Iw8Ba/E5PwkBa/MvPSc1IzUzNzUIoXg5IzczJSSf/kFJZn5ecX/dQsMTAwA)

### Explanation

With `-p`, input is implicitly stored in `$_`, the `040` flag makes space the line terminator which means the code is called for each word/name in the input. `x=` is the in-place string repetition operator which modifies the string in place (e.g. [`$_="abc";$_ x=3;# "abcabcabc"`](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lYpMSlZyZpLJV6hwtbYmqugKDOvxPr/fwA)) and the condition is `$.>1` (`$.` is set to the current 'line' number, although since space is our line end character this is word/name number) `&`ed with `/ /` (if `$_` `m//`atches  , which it will for all but the last word/name). Because of `-p` the result (the string repeated zero or one times depending on the conditional) is implicitly printed.

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 6 bytes

```
~(;);`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v07DWtM64f//aCWv/Iw8JSWvxOT8JCCVmZeek5qRmpmbWqSkFJyckZuZUqIUCwA)

Input is taken in the form of `["name""name""name"]`. Input string is converted to an array, then the first and last elements are separated and discarded, and the result is formatted and outputted.

Answer (score 1):

## [Dash](https://wiki.debian.org/Shell), 24 bytes

```sh
g=\ ${*#* };echo ${g% *}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0kszvj/P902RkGlWktZS6HWOjU5Ix/ISVdV0Kr9//9/Wn6@QlJiERBXAQA)

Input via args.

Also handles the unmentioned case of a single name being provided, returning nothing.

While this feels not *that* clever compared to the posted bash answer, that answer doesn’t work in Dash and this is the best I could muster within its restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `S`, 2 bytes

```
ḢṪ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJTIiwiIiwi4bii4bmqIiwiIiwiW1wiSm9oblwiLCBcIkphY29iXCIsIFwiSmluZ2xlaGVpbWVyXCIsIFwiU2NobWlkdFwiXSJd)

Removes head and tail of list. `S` flag joins by spaces.

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>25</s> 24 bytes

```
{" "/*(1;-1+#t)_t:" "\x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6pWUlDS19IwtNY11FYu0YwvsQIKxFTUcnGlRSt55St4pSbmKQTnZpZkKMWChIITcxPzSjISFcJSUxU8MnNyiiHiTvlJCi5AbmZeemoRRMgrMTe1WMExJ60oNUUhDGiMY05Oap5SLAC7cCOz)

*Down 1 byte by using assignment in expressions*

Does the same thing as the [APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/114938/107017).

Explanation:

```
{" "/*(1;-1+#t)_t:" "\x}    Main function. Takes x as input
                  " "\x     Split x by whitespace
                t:          Assign to variable t
      (       )_            Then delete the following elements in t:
       1;                   The first element, followed by
            #t              The length of t
         -1+                - 1
                            Delete returns back the string as an array, so we need to
     *                      Get the first element of the array
 " "/                       And joined each element in the sub-array by whitespace
                            This is to handle cases like "James Alfred Van Allen",
                            where the result after delete will be ["Alfred", "Van"]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-p`, 20 bytes

Basically identical to [Yelp’s sed answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/221378/11261) and others.

```ruby
gsub /^\S+ |\S+$/,""
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpclm0km6BUuyCpaUlaboWW9KLS5MU9ONigrUVaoCEir6OkhJECqpiwc2Y4MTcxLySjESFsNRUBY_MnJxiLqf8JAUXICszLz21iMsrPyNPwSsxGSjoBRTJSc1IzcxNLVIITs7IzUwpAcoXpyr4JhZl5is4JxYlFifn64aDNCfmFkMsAQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 106 bytes

```go
import."strings"
func f(s string)(o string){l:=Split(s," ")
if k:=len(l);k>2{o=Join(l[1:k-1]," ")}
return}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NVDLaoRAELz7Fc2cFNzA5hQMLuRxCEIgIGwOyxI67oxOnIfMjCfxS3KRQD4if5BfyN-k1d1TVxdFV1V_ftV2-umwarHmoFGaSOrOunDFhA7suw9ic_P3ceF8cNLUnkWiNxWI2MPKJLG9oEFledkpGWKfMmBJJAW0Wa64iVVy2-6uB5sXVtJ22GbtZntcVGPkeOidGc-Ov4vBnCdOhkiazmf54bhaDKxEjSY0CHvO4Ukq5VnK7u07PBImBXe0F7YxUGBFdEGc4g2Xmjsoq0bLU1gUnsMzOmnhAR36ym5e5wOo53sFau7hTgnHT7BHQ5BKsDES1sFbSoEckhXM4YYXChaUoc7A8h1L598k1OrcZ5rW-Q8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `Ṡ`, 2 bytes

```
ḣṫ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faHm00sOdC5RiFywtLUnTtVj2cMfihztXLylOSi6GCi24qROt5JWfkaeko6DklZicnwRmZOal56RmpGbmphaB-MHJGbmZKSVKsRBNAA)

```
ḣ   # head remove
 ṫ  # tail remove
    # Ṡ flag joins by spaces
```

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 70 bytes

```
@set s=.
:l
@if not "%3"=="" set s=%s% %2&shift&goto l
@echo(%s:~2%
```

The loop concatenates arguments starting with the second, shifting them until the third argument is empty. This results in a leading space, so to remove that I prepend with a `.` so that I can slice the string (slicing an empty string produces an erroneous result in Batch). If a trailing space on output is acceptable, then for 66 bytes:

```
@set s=
:l
@if not "%3"=="" set s=%s%%2 &shift&goto l
@echo(%s%
```

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby, 33 bytes

```
->s{$><<s.split[1..-2].join(' ')}
```

Answer (score 0):

## TI-Basic (TI-84 Plus CE), 131 bytes

```
Prompt Str0
inString(Str0," →A
length(Str0)–A→L
sub(Str0,A,L→Str0
" →Str2
For(B,1,L
sub(Str0,B,1)+Str2→Str2
End
inString(Str2," →A
L-A→L
sub(Str2,A,L→Str2
" →Str0
For(B,1,L
sub(Str2,B,1)+Str0→Str0
End
Disp Str0
```

Explanation:

```
Prompt Str0              # 4 bytes, input user string
inString(Str0," →A       # 10 bytes, store the index of the first space in A
length(Str0)–A→L         # 10 bytes, store the length of the string (after removing the first A characters) in L
sub(Str0,A,L→Str0        # 12 bytes, remove first A-1 and last characters of Str0
" →Str2                  # 6 bytes, temporary string to reverse Str0
For(B,1,L                # 7 bytes, reverse Str0 into Str2
sub(Str0,B,1)+Str2→Str2  # 16 bytes
End                      # 2 bytes
inString(Str2," →A       # 10 bytes, store the index of the first space in A
L-A→L                    # 6 bytes, get new length
sub(Str2,A,L→Str2        # 12 bytesremove first A-1 and last characters of Str2
" →Str0                  # 6 bytes, temporary string to reverse Str2
For(B,1,L                # 7 bytes, reverse Str2 into Str0
sub(Str2,B,1)+Str0→Str0  # 16 bytes
End                      # 2 bytes
Disp Str0                # 3 bytes, display final string with (2 trailing spaces)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Sed, <s>23</s> 20 bytes

```
s/\w* (.*) \w*$/\1/
```

Unlike my last sed entry which involved a pipeline from one sed command to another, this one is just a simple, single command, so I'm only counting the bytes of the sed script.

Edited: Plus a 1-byte penalty for the `-r` flag. Thank you, Krixti Lithos, for pointing that out!

Comment: Can you use the `-r` flag to save some bytes from escaping the groups?

Comment: @Kritixi I could but I'm not sure how to score that. Does it count as 2 bytes for the -r flag or only 1 byte?

Comment: It counts as only 1 byte

Comment: @Kritixi Thanks! I just found [this answer on meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/274/794), too. And I see another change I can make to improve it as well.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 28 bytes

```python
print(input().split()[1:-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@19QlJlXopGZV1BaoqGpV1yQkwmkow2tdA1jNf//981MzkhMzVFwL0pNz9ctyM/JVHBJzE0tVvDJL0itAgA)

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure, 107 bytes

```clj
(fn[f](clojure.string/join" "(map #(apply str %)(drop 1(drop-last(take-nth 2(partition-by #(= % \ )f)))))))
```

Unfortunately `drop`/`drop-last` was shorter than `subvec`.

```clj
(defn middle-name [full-name]
  ; Partition the string into a list of names split on spaces, then take every second element
  ;  since partition keeps the spaces 
  (let [sub-names (take-nth 2
                    (partition-by #(= % \ ) full-name))]

    ; ... then join the middle names together on a space.
    (clojure.string/join " "
      ; Drop returns list of chars, so turn them back into strings...
      (map #(apply str %)
           ; Drop the first and last name
           (drop 1
             (drop-last sub-names))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 17 bytes

```
$><<$*[1..-2]*' '
```

Full program, takes input as command line arguments, e.g.:

```
$ ruby middle.rb john jacob jingleheimer shmidt
jacob jingleheimer
```

If we don't mind having the result wrapped in quotation marks, can just use:

```
p$*[1..-2]*' '
$ ruby middle2.rb john jacob jingleheimer shmidt
"jacob jingleheimer"
```

Of course, we can also just take a list and return a list, which can be as short as a 13 byte lambda.

```
->s{s[1..-2]}
# usage:
y = ->s{s[1..-2]};
y.call ["john","jacob","jingleheimer","shmidt"] #=> ["jacob", "jingleheimer"]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>7</s> 3 bytes

```
s1J
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY29DsMgDIR3HoM5GfoI/RkqpC6N1A4Rg0vc4gpDBLw/NaiLrbvvdPeFvbZWDqa1Va16AYZYPehJPxDlXklb8U/pJeJCIVD8YB6eST6KacANaIQE9EgsfNKL80xb/SdL77pBpiT/DBmKS/Oz1wEXbSfJAGMReAzvjFvfhzhkwCglVqmZ7z8)

This is essentially `Input.slice(1,-1)`. The `-1` wraps around to the last item in the input.

Answer (score 0):

## C#, <s>72</s> 69 bytes

Takes a string, returns a string...

```
s=>string.Join(" ",s.Split(' ').Skip(1).TakeWhile(n=>!s.EndsWith(n)))
```

## C# 43 bytes

Takes a string array, returns a string array...

```
s=>s.Skip(1).TakeWhile((n,i)=>i<s.Length-2)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 17 bytes

```
32K-$.;@$.;.@32+"
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pushy#@29s5K2romftAMR6DsZG2kr///9X8srPyFPwSkzOT1LwysxLz0nNSM3MTS1SCE7OyM1MKVECAA)**

```
32 K-    \ Take away 32 from every character.
         \ Now we have the value 0 where there were spaces.
$        \ Until we reach a zero:
 .;      \   Pop a character from the end
         \ Everything after the last space is now removed
@        \ Reverse stack
$.;      \ Do the same
.        \ Pop the leading space
32+      \ Add 32 to everything to map the numbers back to their original characters
@"       \ Reverse and print
```

This is the first method I thought of, and looks like the shortest.

Answer (score 0):

## c, 72 bytes

```
g(char*p){char*e,*s=0;for(;*p;p++)*p-32?0:s?(e=p):(s=p);*e=0;puts(s+1);}
```

[Try it online](https://ideone.com/ZGZIjs)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 16 Bytes

```
x=>x.slice(1,-1)
```

Simple. Return the array passed from the second element to the second from last.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nice submission!

Answer (score 0):

## Lua, 39 bytes

```
print(io.read("*l"):match(" (.+) .+$"))
```

Answer (score 0):

## c, 53 bytes

```
main(a,b)char**b;{for(++b;--a>2;printf("%s ",*++b));}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/c-clang#DchLCoAgEADQq4QQ@N20FTqA204wmuZAapi76OxTb/moAFYO2ouQoUvp7ZNa50p5awysi7061pE4m@@Jafm/EPYlItdyJQeheXJYjzPmiCV22kIuuI8P)

Answer (score 0):

## [Noodel](https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel), 5 [bytes](https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/docs/code_page.html)

Input must be an array of the names.

```
Ẹ⁻2¤İ
```

[Try it:)](https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/editor.html?code=%E1%BA%B8%E2%81%BB2%C2%A4%C4%B0&input=%5B%22James%22%2C%20%22Alfred%22%2C%20%22Van%22%2C%20%22Allen%22%5D&run=false)

---

### How it works

```
      # Pushes the input on implicitly.
Ẹ⁻2¤İ
Ẹ     # Takes the last item of an array and pushes it to the back.
 ⁻2   # Pop the first two items off of the array.
   ¤  # Push the string "¤" onto the stack which represents a space.
    İ # Concatenates the array elements by the "¤" string.
      # Implicitly output the top of the stack to the screen.
```

```html
<div id="noodel" code="Ẹ⁻2¤İ" input='["James", "Alfred", "Van", "Allen"]' cols="10" rows="2"/>

<script src="https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/noodel-latest.js"></script>
<script src="https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/ppcg.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript ES6 23Bytes

`x=>x.pop()*x.shift()||x`

use * instead of && to save 1 byte

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##dc@xDsIgEAbg3acwTGBs36AO6mCaODXRwTiclBYMcA0Qw9B3R6ib0enuku/P3T3hBZ47NYXKYi/S0KTY7GI94UTZJtZeqiFQNs8xcbQetag1jnSgN9KBARskkO2aXIQo5aS09uTO2Oob7/FRwDEDZUfhfqIWpS2qBf7hbbZaSKFMTuS549KoPvwJ@@WGMziFpTmAy69hdS07wSx3pTc)

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 28 bytes

```
proc R n {lrange $n 1 end-1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY89DsIwDIX3nuKp6tqhR@BnQJVYilQGxGBSQyMlTpWEqerZSyiFDS@237M@21GZOXCEkOWAMa@XvDF3zx1aklQaljxDivxEliT2hJYZB21MWI2tu2Gfei0P9qtWu15Qk0pWnXTDPWvLHifVW93F31RgHMlrhx15CsqV5zeI7Jf956JpHrxTaCAYjae0GIWgAktXVtNsLA2ISfr8taCGZwy4NCjiNZvmFw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Gambit Scheme (gsi)](http://gambitscheme.org), 48 bytes

```scm
(lambda(x)(if(>(length x)2)(cadr(reverse x))""))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jdC9jsMgDAfwvU@BmMyQ5R6gUtsbTpFuqtTOLjjBEpDKoKp9@tTJfrkufOn/w4bqI2XqRsw3bvMMSRcB4emAB9hDojK2aJ7uy4HHICD0IKmkJ85a52YINHAhGMynZLeDu1Brr@4uXJpRColrM/aMGUuLaI29EOn4wylVJe5PcpxumvvWHJeRZDPbT7FouEe/ol5Fokic1WlxHzOH9s8NdWnrF4UnnU8oWP3UXZfymLc77TFTVXRIg1BYnohl3ep/LXB@Aw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 29 bytes

```arturo
$->a[take drop a 1(size a)-2]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?71yDc8)